# Что такое абстрактный класс в С++

Tags: c++, классы

Что такое абстрактный класс в С++?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Абстрактный класс в C++ - это класс, в котором объявлена хотя бы одна чисто виртуальная функция.

---

#### Описание

Абстрактный класс используют, когда необходимо создать семейство классов (*много разновидностей монстров в игре*), при этом было бы лучше **вынести общую реализацию и поведение** в отдельный класс. При такой тактике переопределить/дописать придется только специфичные для каждого класса методы (*у каждого монстра своя анимация удара/перемещения*) и/или расширить функциональность класса.

Но возникает возможность создать абстрактный класс, что противоречит архитектуре: как "выделанная общая часть" может быть полноценным классом? Ответ: никак, надо **запретить создавать подобный класс**. Для этого указывают один из методов как чистый виртуальный ( [pure virtual method](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4) ), пример для С++:

```
virtual void f() = 0;
```

тем самым заставляя классы наследники определить реализацию для данного метода. Понятное дело, что такое "ограничение" вызывает зависимость и бьет по гибкости, поэтому в 90% случаев таким методом делают **деструктор**, так как кто-кто, а деструктор в классах, где есть наследование и виртуальные методы нужен всегда. Но не стоит забывать, что при вызове деструктора класс вызывает все деструкторы своих родителей, и поэтому мы **объязаны написать реализацию деструктора**, в случае определения его как чисто виртуального в абстрактном классе:

```
virtual ~IUnit() = 0 
{
}
```

Класс или его наследник перестаёт быть для компилятора абстрактным и экземпляр такого класса может быть создан, как только определена реализация для каждого pure virtual method.

---

#### Отличие от интерфейса

Так как понятия "интерфейс" и "абстрактный класс" путают, приведу их отличия:

1. Каждый интерфейс является абстрактным классом, не каждый абстрактный класс — интерфейс (прим. #1).
2. Интерфейс содержит только public секцию, абстрактный класс не имеет ограничений.
3. Интерфейс содержит только pure virtual methods, абстрактный класс может содержать и поля, и обычные методы в добавок.
4. Интерфейс реализуют, абстрактный класс наследуют (для С++ прим. #1)

Примечение #1: так как **в С++ нету понятия интерфейс на уровне языка**, то программисты симулируют его поведение через абстрактный класс, **наследуя** его.

---

#### Пример

```
class AbstractUnit
{
private:
    int                         m_hp;
    double                      m_speed;

protected:
    virtual void                animateMoveToPoint( const Point2D& moveToPoint ) = 0;

public:
    virtual ~AbstractUnit() = 0 {}
    void                        setHP(const int hp);
    int                         getHP() const;
    void                        setSpeed( const double speed );
    double                      getSpeed() const;

    void                        runTo( const Point2D& moveToPoint );
};


class Archer : public AbstractUnit
{
public:
    Archer()
    {
        setHP( 155 );
        setSpeed( 400 );
    }
    ~Archer()
    {

    }
    void animateMoveToPoint( const Point2D& moveToPoint ) override
    {
        // play particle
        // play sound
        // run skeleton animation
    }
};
```

Интересный, как по мне, способ использовать абстрактный класс в связке с этим паттерном [Template Method Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method).

Comment: Немного по теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/235352/10105

Comment: `надо запретить создавать подобный класс. Для этого указывают один из методов как чисто виртуальным` — добавлю: если чисто виртуальные методы не предусмотрены, можно сделать все конструкторы защищёнными.

Comment: "_надо запретить создавать подобный класс. Для этого указывают один из методов как чисто виртуальным_" - это утверждение попросту неверно. Да, таким образом можно запретить создание, но назначение чисто виртуальных методов совсем не в этом. Их смысл прежде всего в определении общего для иерархии интерфейса. А просто запретить создание можно защищенным коструктором, например, и для этого уж точно не стоит искусственно вводить какие-то чисто виртуальные функции.

Answer (score 5):

Абстрактный класс в C++ - это класс, в котором объявлена хотя бы одна чисто виртуальная функция.