# Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (abstract class and interface)

Tags: ооп, интерфейс, faq, класс

Каковы отличия между абстрактным классом и интерфейсом?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Короткое различие.

Абстрактный класс — это класс, у которого не реализован один или больше методов (некоторые языки требуют такие методы помечать специальными ключевыми словами).

Интерфейс — это абстрактный класс, у которого **ни один** метод не реализован, все они публичные и нет переменных класса.

Интерфейс нужен обычно когда описывается только интерфейс (тавтология). Например, один класс хочет дать другому возможность доступа к некоторым своим методам, но не хочет себя «раскрывать». Поэтому он просто реализует интерфейс.

Абстрактный класс  нужен, когда нужно семейство классов, у которых есть много общего. Конечно, можно применить и интерфейс, но тогда нужно будет писать много идентичного кода.

В некоторых языках (С++) специального ключевого слова для обозначения интерфейсов нет.

Можно считать, что любой интерфейс — это уже абстрактный класс, но не наоборот.

Comment: Не сразу заметил, у вас одна неточность: абстрактный класс может и не содержать pure virtual методов. Более точно было бы определить абстрактым класс, предназначенный для только для наследования.

Comment: А где я писал о "pure virtual методах" ? Я писал о том, что у метода отсутствует реализация. А виртуальный он или нет - это детали реализации языка.

Comment: Проще сказать что интерфейс это частный случай абстрактного класса

Comment: еще можно добавить также что абстрактный класс наследуется..а интерфейс реализуется.....класс может реализовывать множество интерфейсов но наследовать только один абстрактный класс. (на основании этого ябы не сказал что любой интерфейс - это уже абстрактный класс).....а также Интерфейс требует реализации всех методов объявленных в нем (абстрактные методы в абстрактном классе также этого требуют). Методы объявленные как  абстрактные не должны содержать реализации в абстрактном классе.

Comment: В с++ можно наследоваться от произвольного количества абстрактных классов. Употребление слов наследует/реализует - просто соглашение.

Comment: Java и новый C# имеют несколько расширенные определения интерфейса по сравнению с вашим

Comment: Нифига так и не понял на счёт абстрактного класса... Пишем простой класс и интерфейс, наследуем от данного класса 5 других с этим интерфейсом... То же самое?

Comment: Думаю, Вам нужно переформулировать вопрос. Тогда возможно и сами все поймете. Я вопроса не понял.

Comment: К слову, для `C#8+` Ваш ответ более неактуален ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, как и для `Java 8+` =)

Comment: @And, там тоже завезли реализацию интерфейса по умолчанию?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, да. можно делать по умолчанию реализацию.

Comment: @And, эх, куда катится мир...

Comment: ничего, потом введут "чистые интерфейсы" и они будут интерфейсне некуда. И будут продвигаться как самые правильные и крутые.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, ну так, в ногу со временем, как говорится, в будущее =) А по факту, у Java еще абстракцию можно в объект превращать, то есть абстракный класс вызвать как объект и вызвать метод. Тут уж точно из кареты в тыкву, как гворится =)

Answer (score 92):

tl;dr:  Абстрактный класс — средство разработки классов на нижнем уровне, средство для повторного использования кода; интерфейс — средство выражения семантики класса. Таким образом, это совершенно разные, мало связанные между собой понятия.

---

Думайте об этом по-другому.

*Абстрактный класс* — это «заготовка» класса: реализовано большинство методов (включая внутренние), кроме нескольких. Эти несколько нереализованных методов вполне могут быть внутренними методами класса, они лишь уточняют детали имплементации. Абстрактный класс — средство для повторного использования кода, средство, чтобы указать, какой метод обязан быть перекрыт для завершения написания класса.

*Интерфейс* же — это своего рода контракт: интерфейсы используются в определениях чтобы указать, что объект, который будет использован на самом деле, должен реализовывать (для входных параметров) или *будет* гарантированно реализовывать (для выходных параметров) набор методов и (что намного важнее!) иметь определённую семантику. Интерфейс вполне может быть и пустым, тем не менее, имплементировать интерфейс означает поддерживать данную семантику.

Абстрактные классы идеологически схожи с *шаблонами* C++: и те, и другие являются заготовками классов, но шаблону для получения класса нужно специфицировать шаблонные типы, а абстрактному классу — абстрактные методы.

Интерфейсы идеологически схожи с заголовочными файлами C++: они раскрывают методы и скрывают конкретную реализацию.

Вопрос о том, является ли интерфейс или абстрактный класс собственно классом — техническая подробность реализации, зависящая от конкретного языка программирования. Например, в C++ интерфейсы отсутствуют вовсе, и их приходится эмулировать классами без данных. Абстрактный класс в C++ как таковой также отсутствует, но им можно считать любой класс с абстрактными методами. (Отсюда ограничение C++: как минимум 1 абстрактный метод в абстрактном классе.) Также в C++ можно (непрямо) инстанциировать абстрактный класс, вызвать абстрактный метод и (возможно) получить ошибку времени выполнения. В C# интерфейсы и абстрактные классы встроены в язык.

---

Пример (на C#, конкретный язык значения не имеет):

```
// общий код для всех животных
abstract class АбстрактноеЖивотное
{
    public int Возраст { get; protected set; }
    public int Вес { get; protected set; }
    public bool Спит { get; protected set; }
    public void ПодатьГолос()
    {
        if (!Спит && Возраст > ВозрастПрорезанияГолоса)
            РеализацияПодатьГолос();
    }

    abstract protected void РеализацияПодатьГолос();
    readonly protected int ВозрастПрорезанияГолоса;
}

class Собака : АбстрактноеЖивотное
{
    override protected void РеализацияПодатьГолос()
    {
        Гав();
    }
    public void Гав()
    {
        // реализация
    }
    public Собака() { ВозрастПрорезанияГолоса = 2; }
}

class Кошка : АбстрактноеЖивотное
{
    override protected void РеализацияПодатьГолос()
    {
        Мяу();
    }
    public void Мяу()
    {
        // реализация
    }
    public Кошка() { ВозрастПрорезанияГолоса = 1; }
}
```

---

```
interface IЖивотное
{
    int ИнвентарныйНомер { get; }
}

class Лев : ОбитательЗоопарка, IЖивотное
{
    // ...
}

class Зебра : ОбитательЗоопарка, IЖивотное
{
    // ...
}

class Сторож : ОбитательЗоопарка
{
}

// ...
void Инвентаризация()
{
    List<ОбитательЗоопарка> обитатели = // ...
    foreach (var обитатель in обитатели)
        if (обитатель is IЖивотное) // отделяем животных от неживотных
            ДобавитьЖивотное((IЖивотное)обитатель);
}

void ДобавитьЖивотное(IЖивотное животное) // сюда сможет попасть только животное
{
    ...
```

Comment: `IЖивотное` я думаю, даром инквизицию отменили. нельзя так код писать... уже хочется на русском - так на русском. Да и у автора был php...

Comment: @KoVadim: Была бы инквизиция, писал бы на латыни. Почему нельзя? Приведите хотя бы один довод. Это ж пример. А отличие интерфейса от абстрактного класса одно и то же что у PHP, что у C#. (Ну, кроме незначительных технических деталей.)

Comment: Все нормально.Только оператор void пугает.

Comment: Вроде ж оператора `void` у меня нет, только функции. Или я чего-то не вижу?

Comment: это легкий троллинг, что кто то путает 1с и шарп.

а по существу - есть один довод - переключаться долго. Хорошо, у меня капсом, а у людей по две кнопки жать нужно или человек будет смотреть и не понимать, почему переменная класса Сторож не приводиться к типу Стopoж (это для особых любителей загадка)

Comment: Хм :-) Ну, поскольку в C# идентификаторы могут быть в Unicode, то мой код должен быть валидным с т. зр. C#. Так что `void` тоже имел бы смысл. (Вроде бы в C++ тоже можно не-ASCII.) Переключаться да, неудобно, да и коллеги-иностранцы будут ругаться. (У вас среднее «opo» латиницей.)

Comment: смысл киррилических идентификаторов понимается,  когда видишь код с китайскими и арабскими идентификаторами (не забываем, что китайский пишется справа на лево!). Вот рефакторинг такого кода срывает крышу намертво.

Comment: @VladD, не хочу обидеть, но ваши регулярные ответы аналогичного объема смахивают на графоманию. Читать их интересно, но весь их смысл можно передать куда меньшим количеством слов. Ответ @KoVadim и есть пример такого "рефакторинга" ваших ответов.

Comment: @Flammable: Мне кажется, мой ответ делает больший акцент на отличии семантики, нежели на формальные признаки. Впрочем, каждый участник форума судит по своим представлениям. В любом случае, спасибо за ваше мнение.

---
Мне кажется, слишком много вопросов на форуме недалеко уходят от обсуждения синтаксиса и дизайна кода уровня одной функции. Я всегда рад принять участие в обсуждении, когда речь идёт о более серьёзных и интересных вещах. Вы видите в этом проблему или недостаток?

---
Если вы обратите внимание на время, мой ответ появился значительно позже.

Comment: @Flammable: Кстати, специально для тех, кто не любит читать длинный текст, у меня в конце ответа резюме. Перенесу-ка его в начало.

Answer (score 75):

Мне кажется достаточно любопытным, что данный вопрос помечен тегом «ооп», но при этом во многих ответах явно просачиваются специфические аспекты конкретных языков программирования. Я же постараюсь дать ответ исходя из понятий ООП и лишь потом показать, почему вообще это различие появилось в некоторых языках программирования.

Абстрактные классы и интерфейсы имеют определенное отношение к наследованию, точнее к моделированию мира. С их помощью мы хотим выразить, что у определенной группы вещей в нашей системе есть что-то общее: некоторое общее поведение, которое отличает эту группу штуковин от всех остальных.

Допустим, для примера, мы хотим смоделировать кнопки в интерфейсе пользователя. Поскольку мы говорим об ООП, то мы выделим некоторый тип Кнопки с некоторым набором операций (которые определяют поведение) и скрытого состояния, на которое опирается поведение (да, скрытого состояния может и не быть). При этом мы можем выделить три вида операции:

- **Конкретная фиксированная операция, которая должна быть абсолютно стабильно для всех типов кнопок.**
- **Конкретная операция с поведением по умолчанию** (т.е. операция, чье поведение подходит для многих типов кнопок, но могут быть кнопки с другим поведением).
- **Декларация операции без конкретной реализации** (т.е. операция, чье поведение определить невозможно, поскольку на этом этапе не известно разумное поведение по умолчанию или же операции могут слишком сильно различаться у разных кнопок).

Другими словами, тип Кнопки может содержать **невиртуальные методы** (non-virtual methods), **виртуальные методы** (virtual methods) и **абстрактные методы** (abstract methods).

Наличие разных типов методов является очень важным инструментом моделирования и позволяет весьма точно выражать намерения проектировщика. Например, мы можем добавить невиртуальную операцию «Нажатия на кнопку», которая будет делегировать часть своей работы виртуальному (или абстрактному методу) «Обработать нажатие», но при этом всегда выполнять определенную часть работы (прозорливый читатель увидит в этом описании паттерн «Шаблонный метод»).

После того, как мы определили базовый тип, пришло время определить произвольные типы. И тут начинаются вопросы. Точнее, вопросов никаких не возникает, когда у типа есть лишь один непосредственный базовый тип или все базовые типы содержат лишь декларации операций. Не проблема, унаследовать «Кнопку меню» от «Кнопки» и переопределить метод «Нажать на кнопку». Но что, если наш тип «Кнопка меню» будет отнаследован от двух типов с одной и той же виртуальной операцией? Как переопределить лишь одну, а оставить другую? А как быть клиенту нового типа и различить, какую операцию вызвать? А что если у двух базовых типов есть поле с одним именем? А что если у одного базового типа метод «Нажать кнопку» реализован, а у другого – лишь описан в виде декларации?

Нет, все эти проблемы решаемы, и в С++, и Eiffel, и других языках программирования вы можете довольно гибко контролировать, что и как переопределять, что прятать, что выставлять наружу и как вызвать метод определенного базового типа. Но для авторов некоторых языков программирования подобная сложность показалась излишней, и они пошли на хитрость и отделили типы, которые содержат лишь декларации методов в отдельную категорию, и **так появились интерфейсы**.

Теперь будет легко провести разницу между тремя понятиями – интферфейса, абстрактного базового класса и конкретного базового класса.

- **Интерфейс** – описывает некоторое семейство типов и содержит лишь декларации операций (да, я осознанно пишу слово «декларация», а не использую слово «контракт», которое в ООП имеет вполне определенное значение).
- **Абстрактный базовый класс** описывает некоторое семейство типов, но помимо декларации операций может содержать реализации по умолчанию (виртуальные методы) и фиксированные операции (невиртуальные методы).
- **Конкретный класс** описывает некоторое семейство типов, которое готово для использования клиентами. Такой класс не может содержать декларации операций и все его операции должны быть либо фиксированными (невиртуальные методы) или содержать реализацию по умолчанию (виртуальные методы). Есть еще один подвид конкретных классов – **запечатанный (sealed) класс** – это разновидность конкретного класса отнаследоваться от которого невозможно, а значит он может содержать лишь конкретные операции.

Выделение интерфейсов в отдельную категорию полезно не только с точки зрения упрощения реализации языков программирования, но и для выделения разных подходов к моделированию. Так, например, наследование классов моделирует отношение «Является» («Кнопка меню» ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ «Кнопкой»), а базовые классы обычно содержат определенный функционал, тесно связанный с функционалом производного класса. Базовые классы не просто моделируют группу типов, но и позволяют использовать повторно существующий функционал.

Интерфейсы же, по своей природе обладают меньшей связностью (low coupling), поскольку не обладают конкретным поведением, которое может осложнить жизнь класса-наследника. Интерфейсы также могут моделировать отношение «Является» («Кнопка меню» ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ «IКнопкой»), но могут определять и менее жесткое отношение «Может выполнять роль» (CAN DO). Например, интерфейс `IEquatable` из BCL определяет «дополнительное» поведение, которое говорит о возможности типов сравнивать значения объектов.

Answer (score 28):

### Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса в Java

|  | Abstract Class | Interface |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Ключевое слово, используемое для описания** | Для определения абстрактного класса используется ключевое слово `abstract` | Для определения интерфейса используется ключевое слово `interface` |
| **Ключевое слово, используемое для реализации** | Для наследования от абстрактного класса используется ключевое слово `extends` | Для реализации интерфейса используется ключевое слово `implements` |
| **Конструктор** | Определение конструктора разрешено | Объявление/определение конструктора запрещено |
| **Реализация методов по умолчанию** | Допустима | Вплоть до Java 8 разрешено только объявлять методы, но реализация их запрещена. Начиная с Java 8 стала допустима реализация **static** методов, а реализация **non-static** методов стала доступна посредством ключевого слова `default` |
| **Поля** | Может иметь как **static**, так и **non-static** поля (аналогичное относится и к final) | Любое поля интерфейса по умолчанию является `public static final` (и иных иметь не может) |
| **Модификаторы доступа** | Члены абстрактного класса могут иметь любой модификатор доступа: `public`, `protected`, `private`, либо модификатор доступа по умолчанию (`package`) | Члены интерфейса по умолчанию являются `public` (и иной модификатор доступа иметь не могут) |
| **Наследование** | Может расширить (`extends`) любой другой класс и реализовать (`implements`) не более 65535 интерфейсов | Может расширить (`extends`) не более 65535 интерфейсов |

Comment: а в чем задумка с версткой сниппета?

Comment: @Nofate Все просто - я не знаю как сюда по-человечески таблицу впилить :) Если оставлю просто картинку, а потом понадобится обновить, то будет очень неприятно. Таблицы [отсюда](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128302) меня не впечатлили (как-то на них смотреть информацию отличную от чисел не очень удобно).

Comment: Могу разве что посоветовать сделать страницу в ASCII-арто-подобном стиле. [Я даже схемки делаю иногда.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377474/why-does-bitwise-not-1-equal-2/31378616#31378616)

Comment: Сниппет можно положить в `<!-- -->`, тогда его не будет видно.

Comment: @VladD Я попробовал, но что-то у меня ничего из этого не вышло :( Если он сильно мешается, то в принципе я могу его отсюда и убрать, а то все равно на jsfiddle.net сохранил его копию.

Answer (score 21):

Давайте по порядку. *Интерфейс* - это договор/объязательства, которые берёт на себя класс и обязан их выполнить. Допустим: есть массив классов, которые умеют здороваться

```
std::vector <IHellower*> mArr;
class IHellower{
     virtual void Hello() = 0;
}
```

Теперь любой класс вне зависимости от его сложности иерархии и объема может унаследовать (взять на себя объязательство/подписать контракт на выполнения) данного метода и тем самым "станет своим через чужих". Самое приятное тут то, что каким бы обширным бы ни был интерфейс (в данном контексте имеются публичные методы класса) у класса выполняющего данный контракт - из этого массива будет видет только один метод. Пример: есть много графических классов и некоторые из них вы научили реагировать на Blur - запихните их в 1 массив интерфейсов и при надобности вызывайте метод Blur(int value); 
   При использовании интерфейса, мы абстрагируемся от того, что за класс: машина, растение, воздух ... Если он взял на себя обязательства иметь реализацию "Поздороваться" у нас есть **гарантия**, что данный метод будет нам доступен через объект (указатель данного класса) (напоминаю, интерфейс чистовиртуальные методы, в паблик секции, без переменных).

А теперь другая стороная, С++ при всём своем могуществе не имеет понятия интерфейс на уровне языка. Но программисты привыкли к интерфейсу, это удобно, это безопасно (почитайте про Insersion of control) и правильно (с точки зрения архитектуры). Приходится реализовывать "интерфейс" теми инструментами, что предлагает язык С++ - это абстракный класс. Как вы заметили, туда можно запихнуть разные методы (public/protected/private), класс-мемберов(в других языках за переменные в интерфейсе уже проблемы). Было бы ключевое слово interface в С++ и наследовалось бы внятно как в C# - такой бы путаницы небыло.
   Абстрактные классы, как раз, и применяются в случаях выделения общей части классов, но самого такого класса как бы не должно быть (это бессмыслено иметь экземпляр такого класа).

```
class SomeThingLikeABall
{
        private:
            int radius;
            int weight;
        public:
            bool canPlayFootballWithIt() = 0;
            void draw() = 0;
}
```

Как пример, описывали классы мяч и арбуз, нашли общие черты, увидели, что еще будут описывать круглые предметы. Выделили всё это в общий класс и сделали его абстрактным, потому что зачем в системе иметь возможность иметь класс "Нечто кругло, с весом и можно кинуть".

Answer (score 20):

Можно еще добавить, что часто класс описывает некоторую модель, а интерфейс - поведение или роль. Класс называют существительным именем (Dog, Car, House), а к интерфейсу добавляют окончание -able, чтобы описывало некоторое действие или свойство (Moveable, Eatable, Buildable). Например, мы создаем игру в жанре стратегия. У нас есть разные фракции, в каждой из них есть разные юниты (воины, строители) и мы для каждого юнита создаем отдельный класс. Но в поведении между всеми этими юнитами есть много общего - у любого воина независимо от фракции есть способность драться (Attackable), у любого строителя независимо от фракции есть способность строить (Buildable), а у абсолютно всех юнитов есть способность двигаться (Moveable). Таким образом можно описать взаимодействие всех ролей с помощью множественного наследования интерфейсов.

Comment: Что-то спорное утверждение... Очень похоже на один из частных случаев.

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что это как правило и так нужно делать. Когда я читал про такое - это было скорее рекомендацией для подобного примера.

Comment: Хотел написать похожий ответ, но вовремя увидел - отличный ответ. Вот всеми руками за. Кратко, по сути, без огромных таблиц, сравнений, исходников. Аплодирую стоя.

Answer (score 15):

Можно я влезу )

1. класс с **виртуальной** функцией/функциями называется - **абстрактным**
2. **абстрактный класс** может иметь одну или несколько **чисто** виртуальных функций
3. если **абстрактный класс** имеет хотя бы одну **чисто виртуальную** функцию, объект такого класса нельзя создавать, а только наследовать причем **чисто виртуальные** функции должны быть переопределены в будущем.
4. **интерфейс** класса - это указание/договор с программистом о том, как программист может использовать этот класс. т.е. получается **интерфейс** - это все открытые (**public**) данные к которым может обратится программист.

по сути написал что и @VladD только простым языком

```
ps - модераторам почему я комментировать не могу?
```

Comment: > 2) астрактный класс может иметь одну или несколько чистых виртуальных функций

Может и не иметь.

Comment: ну вот я и пишу **может** )

Comment: первый пункт - ошибка. Обычный класс также может иметь виртуальные функции/методы.

второй пункт - там мелкая ошибка. Но пункт три подсказывает, что @perfect ее не до конца осознал. Абстрактный класс объязан иметь хотя бы одну чистую виртуальную функцию (она же абстрактная).

Comment: @KoVadim вы меня первым пунктом с ног сшибли объясните почему

 Обычный класс также может иметь виртуальные функции/методы?

Comment: да, а кто ему мешает?

Comment: как только виртуальная функция появится в обычном классе он уже автоматически становится абстрактным, по моему так, если нет переубедите меня лучше фактами

Comment: @perfect, не путайте виртуальные и чисто виртуальные функции. Виртуальные функции имеют реализацию и могут (но не обязаны) быть переопределены. Чисто виртуальные функции обязаны быть переопределены в наследнике (если только он тоже не абстрактный).

Comment: @fori1ton , а я о чем в третьем пункте написал?

Comment: @perfect

начните с главного отличия абстрактного класса от обычного - экземпляр первого нельзя создать. Если у класса есть обычные виртуальные методы - его можно создать.

Можно по другому зайти. Когда Вы пишете наследника абстрактного класса, то переопределенные абстрактные методы (которые в большинстве языков обязаны быть виртуальными) также будут виртуальными. Но класс-наследник от этого не будет ведь абстрактным? (если только не забудет реализовать пару методов/функций).

Comment: @perfect, а что вы в предыдущем своём комменте написали? Вот код: http://ideone.com/4Ua1Qr Если бы класс А из-за наличия виртуальной функции был абстрактным, я бы не смог создать его экземпляр. Наличие _виртуальной_ функции не делает класс абстрактным. Класс становится абстрактным при наличии _чисто виртуальной_ функции.

Comment: Выясняется, что в Java все чуточку по другому. Там может быть абстрактный класс без абстрактных методов! ([пруф](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)) Но там есть специальное ключевое слово, которым нужно пометить такой класс. Кстати, там в главе "Abstract Classes versus Interfaces" есть ответ с java точки зрения.

Comment: Ещё любопытный факт: понятие виртуальных функций есть толко в C++. В других распространённых ООП языках метод по умолчанию считается виртуальным (т. е. его можно переопределить) если явно не указано обратное (модификатор `final`)ю

Comment: Для delphi, например, все утверждения неверны чуть более чем полностью. Абстрактный класс - это абстрактный класс, у которого есть соответствующая директива. Он может вообще не содержать ни одного абстрактного метода. Абстрактный класс не может быть инстанцирован.  
А вот класс, содержащий абстрактные (pure virtual в терминах c++) методы, инстанцировать можно. И только при обращении к абстрактным методам будет исключение.   
У интерфейсов важным является то, что класс может предоставлять несколько интерфейсов ну и плюс сигнатура методов заранее известна.

Answer (score 13):

Я в ООП новичок, но осмелюсь высказать свою версию происходящего.

Сначала программисты изобрели «интерфейсы» - так как это вещь в ООП очень удобная. И тут внезапно выяснилось, что некоторые разные классы, реализующие один и тот же интерфейс, могут содержать практически одинаковые куски кода! А раскидывать одни и те же куски кода по разным местам проекта – это уже не есть хорошо. И тут изобрели «абстрактный класс», который может выполнять не только роль интерфейса, но и служить сущностью для **выделения общих участков кода** – т.е. выполнять ту работу, которую не смог бы выполнить интерфейс. Т.е. «абстрактный класс» помогает избежать дублирования кода – ведь одна из главных методик работы программиста – умение находить общие участки кода и «выносить их за скобки», так сказать, что способствует уменьшению дублирования кода. Т.е. в основе всего этого лежит борьба со сложностью разработки и сопровождения программ и «абстрактный класс» помогает решать эту задачу.

Answer (score 7):

1. В некоторых языках(Java ... ) возможно наследование от нескольких интерфейсов, но только от 1-го класса.
2. Interface не реализовывает методы, а только предоставляет права доступа для их использования (Можно представить себе интерфейс - как вуаль или контракт на права доступа к чему-то). В абстрактном классе вы можете реализовать метод и переопределить его в наследуемом класе, просто вы не можете создавать объекты этого класа.

Comment: По сути верно, но увы, ответ чисто технический. Ну примерно как ответ на вопрос чем отличается человек от собаки: ну знаете, собака это существо семейства псовых, а человек из семейства приматов - верно конечно, но не отражает сути.

Answer (score 6):

Абстрактный класс может иметь переменные, конструкторы, свойства и реализации методов. Интерфейс - только сигнатуры методов.

Answer (score 6):

Interface - это класс, который по умолчанию является абстрактным. По сути интерфейс нужен для того, чтобы от него наследоваться.

Answer (score 6):

## Что такое абстрактный класс?

Абстрактный класс - это класс, который объявляется абстрактным - может включать или не включать абстрактные методы. Абстрактные классы не могут быть созданы, но они могут быть подклассифицированы. Когда абстрактный класс подклассифицирован, подкласс обычно предоставляет реализации для всех абстрактных методов в его родительском классе.

Я немного расшифрую понятие абстрактного класса. В связи с вопросом почему я использую абстрактный класс. Иногда я просто добавляю фразу `abstract` к  классу, по причине того что некоторые методы должны имплементироваться пользоватем этого класса и указываю какие иммено методы должны быть абстрактными. Для чего это нужно, впрочем если пользователь будет пользоваться абстрактными классом, то часть его методов уже имеет дефолтную имплементацию, которую можно перекрыть, а абстрактные методы также перекрываются, только синтаксис предполагает наличие модификатора `abstract` и отсутствие тела метода, определяя тем самым только сигнатуру. Это свойство языка и отличие от других объектно-ориентированных языков. Фраза `abstract` не обязательно предполагает абстрактность или такое толкование, а лишь возможность указания методов, которые необходимо перекрывать в классах наследниках.

## Что такое абстракция в программировании?

В объектно-ориентированном программировании абстракция является одним из трех основных принципов (наряду с инкапсулированием и наследованием). Благодаря процессу абстракции программист скрывает все, кроме соответствующих данных об объекте, чтобы уменьшить сложность и повысить эффективность.

## Может ли абстрактный класс не иметь абстрактных методов?

Да, мы можем иметь абстрактный класс без абстрактных методов, поскольку оба являются независимыми понятиями. Объявление абстрактного класса означает, что он не может быть создан сам по себе и может быть только подклассифицирован. Объявление абстрактного метода означает, что метод будет определен в подклассе.

## Можете ли вы создать объект абстрактного класса в Java?

Если бы мы могли создать объект абстрактного класса и вызвать его метод без тела (поскольку метод является чисто виртуальным), то он бы дал ошибку. Вот почему мы не можем создать объект абстрактного класса. Короче говоря, законно иметь публичный конструктор абстрактного класса. Абстрактный класс нельзя создать, но можно пользоваться если есть соответствующая имплементация этого класса. Сама абстракция в отличие от наследования предполагает отсутствие кода имплементации. Если вы используете абстрактный класс то вы можете ограничиться декларированием методов. Интерфейсы это такие абстрактные классы у которых все методы абстрактные.

Comment: А почему В объектно-ориентированном программировании абстракция является одним из трех основных принципов (наряду с инкапсулированием и наследованием). А почему из трех? А полиморфизм?

Comment: @Mike Потому, что так было задумано создателями ООП, это можно лучше понять если почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/858504/204920

Comment: На счет того. что мы не можем создать объект абстрактного класса, утверждение не верное. В корне не верное. Все там можно. Прежде, чем утверждать, сначала советую пробовать. Создаем `abstract class C` определяем в нем `public C(){}` публичный конструктор, определяем `public void m(){}` публичный метод, создаем объект `C c = new C(){};c.m();` И Оо чудо. все работает.

Comment: @And, но разве это не будет уже неабстрактный, аноминый класс, разширяющий абстстрактный? Если в ваш пример добавить абстрактный метод, то при создании анонимного класса компилятор заставит вам его, метод, реализовать.

Comment: Тоже самое верно и для интерфейсов - можно написать ваш пример заменив класс на интерфейс и внешне ничего не изменится и будет работать, но это не будет означать, что вы создали экземпляр интерфейса. Также будет создан анонимный класс, реализующий интерфейс.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, суть вне в том, что, что-то реализовывать или нет, а в том, что можно создать, значит утверждение не верное, и нужно пояснять правильно, а не утверждать. что нельзя.

Comment: @And, не готов с вами согласиться( По моему утверждение `нельзя создать экземпляр абстрактного класса` верно. Так же как и утверждение `можно создать экземпляр анонимного класса, расширяющего абстрактный класс`

Answer (score 3):

Класс - это всегда интерфейс + реализация. Хотя бы частичная, как в случае с абстрактным классом.

Интерфейс - это способ полностью отделить интерфейс от реализаци. Т.е. как полностью абстрактный класс. Служит для описания котракта поведения объекта при взаимодействии с внешним окружением.

|  | Interface | Abstract Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Relationship | Контракт | Is a |
| Суть | Описание контракта | Шаблон для группы классов |
| Когда использовать | Всегда (если не нужно state) | Только когда нужно state |
| State | Нет | Может иметь |

Comment: Написали бы хотя бы, что Ваш ответ относится исключительно к Java (если что - вопрос был более общий)

Comment: @KotVadim, да, как-то я сразу в контексте Java ответил. Изменил ответ - попробовал ответить менее Java-специфично.