# Система плагинов

Tags: c#, плагин, рефлексия

Захотелось научиться работать с отражением и вот этим всем.
Начал с простенького, решил написать подключаемый плагин, который автоматически подгрузится из именной папки.

Что бы не мучиться с отражением методов и прочей нечистью на ум конечно же приходит наследование и полиморфизм.
То есть мне нужен какой-то базовый класс с начальным функционалом от которого будут наследоваться все другие плагины.

То есть нужно сделать отдельную библиотеку с апи, которую будут использовать обе стороны (программа и плагин).

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    void Loaded();
}
```

Вот такой класс придумал в этой библиотеке.
Теперь я могу спокойно ее подключать к плагину и наследоваться.

```
public class Test : IPlugin
{
    #region Implementation of IPlugin

    public void Loaded() => Console.WriteLine( "Hello World" );

    #endregion
}
```

Вот у меня уже две библиотеки, одна с моим апи, другая его использует.
Теперь мне нужно как-то загрузить сборку с плагином и использовать его методы.
Вот тут мне и нужна помощь.

Так как библиотека плагина использует другую библиотеку с апи, я не смогу ее так просто загрузить, так как выскочит ошибка мол либе не хватает референсов. Как правильно загрузить плагин указав что сборка которая ему нужна уже загружена в программу?

Вот код которым я пытаюсь что-то наколдовать:

```
private static void Main ( string[] args )
    {
        var pluginsPath = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\Plugins";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles( pluginsPath , "*.dll" );

        foreach ( var file in files )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( $"Trying load: {file}" );
            Assembly assembly;

            try { assembly = Assembly.Load( file ); }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( ex.Message );
                continue;
            }

            var types =
                assembly.GetTypes().Where( type => type.IsClass && type.GetInterface( nameof( IPlugin ) ) != null );

            foreach ( var type in types )
            {
                var plugin = Activator.CreateInstance( type ) as IPlugin;

                if ( plugin == null )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "Null" );
                    continue;
                }

                plugin.Loaded();
            }
        }
    }
```

Падает еще на первом try с сообщением:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.IO.FileLoadException" в mscorlib.dll
>   Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "C:\Users\anweledig\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Anweledig\ConsoleApplication\bin\Debug\Plugins\TestPlugin.dll" либо одну из их зависимостей. Данное имя сборки или база кода недействительны. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131047)

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед, используйте [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Если хотите всё же грузить всё руками, покажите код и Fusion Log из exception'а.

Comment: @VladD человек же делает плагины в целях изучения рефлекшена. а не учит рефлекшн в целях написания плагина. mef не поможет :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Тогда Fusion Log нужен. Может, плагин лежит в непонятном месте. И рефлексия не поможет, если плагинная система правильная (ну кроме первоначальной загрузки какого-нибудь `IPlugin`).

Comment: `public abstract void Unload();` — это у вас не получится без грязных трюков. Выгрузить загруженную сборку нельзя (разве что только с AppDomain'ом).

Comment: И почему абстрактный класс, а не интерфейс? Если вы пришли из C++, это [**не** одно и то же](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/235464/10105).

Comment: @VladD Unload это как обработчик события задумывалось, нужно было написать OnUnload, смысл изначально даже заключался не в том чтоб выгрузить сборку, а чтоб выгрузить плагин из листа. По поводу абстрактного класса, у меня там была сначала некоторая реализация, я в принципе вижу разницу и плюсы интерфейсов, но суть это никак не поменяет, не загружается это дело. Сейчас попробую добавить больше информации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете просто загрузить другую библиотеку. Все ее зависимости будут автоматически загружены.

Проблема может быть только в случае, если библиотека лежит не в той же папке, в которой лежит ваше приложение, и вы при этом загружаете ее через `Assembly.LoadFrom`. Чтобы это обойти, вам нужно указать рантайму что зависимости надо искать в папке плагина, а не в папке вашего приложения. Тогда можно будет использовать обычный `Assembly.Load` и заодно заработает станадартный механизм загрузки сборок.

Для этого можно использовать создание аппдомена с указанием [`AppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomainsetup.applicationbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Т.е. схема примерно такая:

У вас есть базовая dll для плагинов - MyApp.SDK, в ней базовый класс (а лучше - интерфейс):

```
public abstract class Plugin
{
    public abstract void Loaded();
    public abstract void Unload();
}
```

в ней же код загрузки и вызова плагина (для простоты)

```
public static class PluginInvoker
{
    public static void InvokePlugin()
    {
        var pluginAssembly = Assembly.Load("SomePlugin");
        var pluginType = pluginAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(Plugin).IsAssignableFrom(t)).Single();
        Plugin plugin = (Plugin)pluginType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(null);
        plugin.Loaded();
    }
}
```

есть реализация этого плагина в SomePlugin.dll:

```
public class Test: MyApp.SDK.Plugin
{
    public override void Loaded()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loaded");
    }

    public override void Unload()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unloaded");
    }
}
```

в SomePlugin есть референс на MyApp.SDK.

И есть главное приложение, в котором есть ссылка на MyApp.SDK, но нет ссылки на SomePlugin:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
    setup.ApplicationBase = @"C:\Projects\MyApp\SomePlugin\bin\Debug\";

    AppDomain pluginDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("plugin", null, setup);
    pluginDomain.DoCallBack(PluginInvoker.InvokePlugin);
}
```

`ApplicationBase` задает папку, откуда AppDomain будет загружать сборки - т.к. это папка плагина, то все, на что он ссылается, будет корректно загружено.

Если плагины подгружаются из подпапки приложения (например, из Plugins), то в вместо [`AppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomainsetup.applicationbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) можно использовать [`AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Если же при этом плагины вообще не планируется выгружать, и все плагины лежат в одной папке (без подпапок на каждый из плагинов) - то можно обойтись без отдельного AppDomain, просто дописав путь к папке с плагинами в секцию [`app.config/<probing>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

код примера на github: https://github.com/PashaPash/PluginLoadSample

Comment: Спасибо большое. Буду разбираться.

Comment: @anweledig держите рабочий пример: https://github.com/PashaPash/PluginLoadSample

Comment: @PashaPash: А почему не старый добрый `AssmeblyResolve`? Всё же работа через границу домена — не самая быстрая штука.

Comment: @VladD `AssemblyResolve` потянет за собой `LoadFrom` - а это потенциально приключения с контекстом загрузки, ифы на системные сборки и прочие костыли. Ну и автор все равно захочет плагины выгружать рано или подзно, так что домен нужен будет.

Comment: @PashaPash: Вы уверены насчёт системных сборок? Майкрософтовский официальный пример не делает if'ы. (И вообще, рекомендует app.config.)

Comment: @PashaPash: Так что наверное для плагинов проще всего [`app.config/<probing>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @VladD да, или PrivateBinPath - но только если плагины лежат в подпапке приложения. В общем случае - ApplicationBase. Когда я писал ответ - дополнения с GetCurrentDirectory еще не было, да и в семпле у меня загрузка из внешней папки.

Comment: @VladD дополнил