# Что правильнее использовать, абстрактный класс, в котором все методы абстрактные или несколько интерфейсов?

Tags: ооп

Например, есть абстрактный класс `АбстрактныйАвтомобиль`.
У него есть 4 метода - `повернутьНалево()`, `повернутьНаправо()`, `начатьДвижение()`, `затормозить()`.
Есть 3 наследника - `ШевролеКруз`, `ШевролеЛанос` и `ФордМондео`. Я не разбираюсь в автомобилях, но предположим что поворот руля налево, поворот руля направо, начала движения и торможение для разных марок автомобилей реализовано по-разному. То есть мы не можем реализовать ни один из методов в классе `АбстрактныйАвтомобиль`. Придется их все сделать абстрактными.
А в классах `ШевролеКруз`, `ШевролеЛанос`, и `ФордМондео` реализовать эти методы для каждого по-своему. Или же правильнее объявить 3 интерфейса - `Turnable` с методами `повернутьНалево()` и `повернутьНаправо()`, `Startable` с методом `начатьДвижение()` и `Stopable` с методом `затормозить()`?

Читал, что нужно мыслить на уровне интерфейсов, а не классов. И что вообще абстрактный класс, в котором есть только абстрактные методы - плохой тон. С другой стороны читал что если есть отношение является то нужно использовать наследование. А тут явно есть отношение является.
Что же тут правильнее использовать?
Растолкуйте пожалуйста.

**UPD:** Написали, что есть дубликат моего вопроса, вот он:
[Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (abstract class and interface)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235352/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0)
По-моему это все-таки не совсем то..
Там просто разбираются отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса. Я перечитал много таких статей прежде чем задавать вопрос. Если бы они для меня все прояснили, я бы его и не стал задавать. Мне была интересна именно ситуация, когда и отношения является есть и связь между классами, но при этом абстрактный класс вынужден иметь только абстрактные методы. Конечно я понимаю, что если в классах 10 методов реализовываются одинаково а один нет, то надо применять наследование. А вот в описанной выше ситуации я не понимал что нужно делать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235352/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: [И Вы в этом не одиноки...](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прелесть интерфейсов в вашем контексте вы оцените, когда у вас появится другое транспортное средство, например мотоцикл.

К примеру у вас будет интерфейс:

```
public interface Movable{
    public void Move();
}
```

Тогда, вы можете реализовать в нужных классах его, что будет обозначать, что средство может двигаться. Теперь вы можете в одну коллекцию сложить разные классы `List<Movable>`, где могут быть и мотоциклы, и машины. В случае с абстрактным классом у вас бы такое не получилось.

Проблема, лично для меня, абстрактных классов в том, что при использование вы завязываетесь на конкретную реализацию.

> И что вообще абстрактный класс, в котором есть только абстрактные
>   методы - плохой тон.

Это вообще бессмысленно. Делать абстрактный класс имеет смысл, если у вас много общей логики, которую вы в него вынесите.

Comment: Спасибо! Отличное объяснение, именно такое искал) Получается, что использования интерфейса в программе можно сравнить с приемом таблеток для профилактики в реальной жизни? В данной момент кажется не нужным, а потом может принести большую пользу? Так же и тут, изначально мне кажется что я буду работать только с Автомобилями и что вполне сойдет абстрактный класс. Но в будущем требования к программе могут измениться и понадобится добавить велосипед, и вот в этот момент то что я заранее позаботился о расширяемости кода очень поможет, так?

Comment: То есть интерфейсы нужны для того что бы код был расширяемым, правильно я понял?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров а так же для унификации связей в системе и уменьшении связанности. Рассматривайте интерфейс как контракт, который явно задаёт, что должен делать элемент (класс).

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров интерфейсы - это задел на будущее, как минимум. Я часто сталкивался с системами, когда люди предварительно не продумали архитектуру и завязались на конкретную реализацию, потом было сложно переписывать. Часто такое замечаю в контексте работы с базой данной, когда в какой-то момент решили заменить СУБД

Comment: Вот у меня так же, в моем нынешнем проекте. Создал класс, который работает с базой данных. Естественно везде используются объекты этого класса. А надо получается создать интерфейс DBConnectable, в котором будут методы readDataFromDB и putDataIntoDB и имплементировать этот интерфейс в том классе, который у меня работает с базой? Даже не смотря на то что этот класс у меня один и сейчас вроде бы я никакой выгоды не получу? зато смогу в программе использовать ссылку на интерфейс, а не на класс. И если потом в другом классе имплементирую этот же интерфейс, смогу легко сделать замену?

Comment: Если вы зададите интерфейс вашему классу по работе с БД, то потом, к примеру, в случае смены БД, придётся просто написать новый класс, реализующий интерфейс. Места, где идёт вызов методов интерфейса в других частях системы не надо будет менять. Это при условии, что ваш класс, реализующий интерфейс будет возвращать объекты, не зависящие от реализации.

Comment: То есть в других классах, которые взаимодействуют с тем который работает с базой я смогу создавать методы, в которых будет ссылка уже типа интерфейса, а не класса, правильно? И если у меня появится новая база, я смогу сделать новый класс, который тоже будет имплементировать интерфейс DBConnectable, а сигнутуры этих методов мне менять не придется, правильно?

Comment: Да, придётся менять лишь реализацию, сигнатура останется та же. Смотрите на интерфейсы, как не заголовочные файлы в С++. Что-то похожее)

Comment: Да, я понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Suvirtuf: Последний вопрос) Получается, по этой же причине лучше писать List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); чем ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(), так?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров именно. Если вы зададите как List, то потом можете экземпляр любой коллекции создать, который реализует List. Так же с Map, его реализуют и HashMap, и SortedHashMap, и TreeMap и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

Вы должны различать интерфейсы — средства проектирования классов, и абстрактные классы — средство имплементации, повторного использования кода.

С точки зрения системы типов, коду, который пользуется вашими классами, начхать, одинаково ли устроен метод *ПовернутьНаправо* у классов *Бэха* и *Фордфокус*. Им главное, что эти методы существуют. Поэтому наружу должен быть виден интерфейс, который гарантирует существование нужных методов.

Теперь, с точки зрения имплементации, которая есть сугубо ваша внутренняя кухня, вы можете заметить, что *ШевролеКруз* и *ШевролеЛанос* в силу текущих подробностей реализации рулят налево совершенно одинаково. Вот вы, чтобы не копипастить код, помещаете общий метод в абстрактный суперкласс, и таким образов расшариваете его между двумя имплементациями.

Таким образом, для внешнего клиента важен интерфейс. А вот для эффективной имплементации вы вполне можете воспользоваться абстрактными классами. (Но объясните пользователю, что абстрактные классы — ваша приватная штука, и их иерархия может поменяться при первом же рефакторинге.)

---

В свете этого становится понятно, почему прохладно относятся к абстрактным классам без методов. Если у вас есть такой класс, но не служит делу повторного использования кода, то он, скорее всего, и не нужен.

Однако: в некоторых языках (например, C++), понятия интерфейса нету вовсе. Вот в них-то и приходится эмулировать интерфейс при помощи пустых абстрактных классов.

---

Отдельный вопрос — выстраивание иерархии классов. Вам может понадобиться общий предок нескольких классов, если он несёт свою смысловую нагрузку в программе. А вот создание общего предка лишь для того, чтобы передавать разные объекты в общую функцию — не очень верная идея, лучше для этого использовать интерфейсы.

Answer (score 0):

Любая машина может поворачивать направо, налево, тормозить и ехать. И в абстрактном классе и в интерфейсе достаточно просто прописать эти методы. А как именно они реализуются - это нужно решать при создании класса отдельной машины.

Разница между абстрактным классом и интерфейсом в том, что при использовании абстрактного класса можно сделать машину, которая будет только поворачивать или только ехать, или только тормозить, а также машину которая может летать или плавать. Абстрактный класс не ограничивает наследников.

А при использовании интерфейса машина хоть и сможет летать при надобности, но обязательно должна и поворачивать, и тормозить, и ехать. Интерфейс требует реализации всех методов.