# Разница наследования от простого или же от абстрактного класс

Tags: java, классы

```
class A {
    int x;
    int y;

    ..getters and setters
}

abstract class B {
    int x;
    int y;

    ..getters and setters
}

class C extends A {
    int w;
    int z;

    ..getters and setters
}

class D extends B{
    int w;
    int z;

    ..getters and setters
}
```

difference?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Одна из [особенностей абстрактных классов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235352/) заключается в том, что они могут реализовывать часть логики, но при этом часть методов может остаться нереализованной. Реализацию обязаны добавить наследники.

Соответственно если у вас класс `B` не объявляет никаких абстрактных членов, то с т.з. наследников никакой разницы не будет. Единственная разница будет заключаться в том, что вы не сможете создавать экземпляры класса `B` (это другая особенность абстрактных классов).

Answer (score 3):

Разница только в том, что вы не можете создавать объекты абстрактного родительского класса (B)- только его потомков (D). В случае класса A могут существовать как объекты самого родительского класса A, так и дочернего класса C. Смысл абстрактных классов в том, чтобы предотвратить создание объектов для тех классов, которые не предназначены для использования напрямую, а только для создания потомков на их базе. Это своего рода полуфабрикаты, которые нуждаются в доработке (конкретизации).

Comment: Получается дело только в потомках и архитектурном смысле. Никаких других технических ограничении они не несут?

Comment: Не очень понял, что вы имеете в виду. Да, если два родительских класса отличаются только наличием/отсутствием слова `abstract`,  и имеют дочерние классы, отличающиеся друг от друга лишь указанием базовых классов, то в использовании таких потомков никакой разницы не будет.