# Стоит ли использовать таким образом интерфейсы в c#?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, интерфейс

Задумался о таком использовании интерфейсов. Соответственно возник такой вопрос, стоит ли использовать подобный код?

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    int LegsCount { get; }
}

public interface ICat : IAnimal
{
    string Voice { get; }
}

public abstract class FourLegsAnimal : IAnimal
{
    public int LegsCount => 4;
}

public class DummyCat : FourLegsAnimal, ICat
{
    public string Voice => "I am dummy cat";
}
```

Код работает, но вот не знаю, имеется ли "запашок" у такого кода

Comment: а почему `IAnimal` не может сразу содержать `string Voice`?

Comment: @tCode, как насчет рыб?

Comment: @AlexKrass есть некоторые виды которые издают звук, вроде как)

Comment: @AlexKrass, рыбы же не животные?

Comment: @koks_rs тоже так подумал, но загуглил - написано животные

Comment: Да, и правда, Домен:  Эукариоты,
Царство:  Животные,
Тип:  Хордовые,
Группа:  Рыбы

Comment: Такой код вызывает у меня чувство усложнения структуры и желание его переписать. Мы может дробить сущности очень много и долго, но основная задача стоит в упрощении понимания программы. В данном случае, если наша задача создать просто кошку, то зачем все лишнее? Но если это будет оправдано, то почему нет?

Comment: Пока ничего ужасного. Ошибка в том, что вы делаете интерфейсы ради интерфейсов, а нужно делать интерфейсы ради упрощения кода.

Comment: Просто я с подобным паттерном никогда не сталкивался, вот и задумывался как его применить. Правда может иерархия объектов не совсем верная

Comment: Просто я пришел из с++, и этот код немного меня смутил. Даже интересно, возможно в с++ так написать. Просто никогда таким способом не пользовался

Comment: @koks_rs стоит перенести вопрос на http://biology.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @LmTinyToon, еще почитайте ответы тут [Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235352/Отличия-абстрактного-класса-от-интерфейса-abstract-class-and-interface). Мне кажется тут вопрос больше в том, когда использовать интерфейс и когда абстрактный класс, поскольку они взаимозаменяемы. Переход от интерфейса к абстрактному классу должен быть осознанным и необходимым решением с точки зрения архитектуры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, говоря об объектной ориентации, не имеет смысла дробить на интерфейсы без необходимости для дизайна программы. Иначе можно получить бесконечное множество интерфейсов: `IFourLegs`, `IHaveWhiskers`, `IDrinkWater`, `ILiveOnEarth`, `IVertebrate`, `ICarbonBasedLifeForm`, `IHavingNameInEnglish`, `IHavingSeparateGenders`, и так далее.

Прикиньте сначала вашу иерархию объектов, прикиньте, в какие группы вы будете их группировать и зачем, и только на основе этого стройте ваши интерфейсы.

Возможно, имеет смысл начать вовсе без интерфейсов, написать прототип, и в процессе написания прототипа вдумчиво добавлять нужные интерфейсы (и бить себя по пальцам, чтобы не добавлять ненужные).

Comment: да, думаю в общем случае именно так. Хотя мне кажется такой код симпатичен в следующем случае (возможно изначально я выбрал не совсем верную иерархию)

Comment: Что, если модель имеет иерархию, и я хочу что каждый класс реализовывал интерфейс с "read-only" методами. И соответственно использовать эти интерфейсы в gui объектах. Gui объекты тоже будут иметь такую же иерархию. Думаю при таком подходе такой код будет иметь смысл (боюсь что слишком неопределенно обьяснил)

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Вооот, вы уже думаете в терминах архитектуры приложения. Это намного лучше. Если интерфейса нужен для приложения, он имеет смысл.