# interface cannot contain fields Что это значит?

Tags: c#

Где здесь ошибка? Я не могу понять.

```
 interface IMesaj{
    string mesaj; 
    public void Yaz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mesaj);
    }
    void Yaz(string mesaj);
}
```

Comment: это значит, что в интерфейсе _нельзя_ указывать _поля_

Comment: уберите картинку и добавте код текстом.

Comment: для решения замени _interface_ На _class_. Хотя, чтобы у тебя это заработало, нужно еще добавить _abstract_

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (abstract class and interface)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/235352/186999)

Comment: Это экзаменационный вопрос. Почему сдесь ошибка?
string mesaj; 
    public void Yaz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mesaj);
    }

Comment: _Почему здесь ошибка? `string mesaj; public void Yaz() { Console.WriteLine(mesaj); }`_ -  в данном коде **нет** ошибки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> string mesaj;
> ```

В интерфейсе можно объявлять только свойства и методы. Никаких полей.

> ```
> public void Yaz()
> ```

В интерфейсе всё публично, поэтому никаких явных `public`.

> ```
> {
>     Console.WriteLine(mesaj);
> }
> ```

Интерфейс не может содержать никаких реализаций, только объявления.

Comment: В будущем возможно, [сможет](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/d7c01cd036d271192f0af3613bcc56a96d205419/proposals/default-interface-methods.md)

Comment: @VladislavKhapin, интересно :)

Comment: Всем Спасибо)) А как я могу поблогадарить вас? можно ли мне добовлять репутацию кому нибудь если он мне помог?

Comment: @MansurMahmutov, проголосовать за (стрелочка вверх над числом голосов) понравившиеся ответы и принять один из них нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Элементами интерфейса могут быть методы, свойства, события и индексаторы.

Интерфейсы не могут содержать константы, поля, операторы, конструкторы, деструкторы или типы, а также любые статические элементы.

Элементы интерфейса не могут быть объявлены с модификаторами abstract, public, protected, internal, private, virtual, override и static.

Поэтому данное объявление интерфейса

```
interface IMesaj{
    string mesaj; 
    public void Yaz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mesaj);
    }
    void Yaz(string mesaj);
}
```

некорректное так как, во-первых, оно содержит объявление поля `string mesaj`, а, во-вторых, содержит определение метода `Yaz`, к тому же имеющего модификатор `public`.

Comment: Спасибо)) Почитал про отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса. Теперь все понял.