# Надобность абстрактных классов

Tags: java, интерфейс

А вы используете абстрактные классы в своих проектах/на работе? Если да, то почему?

Хочу понять смысл абстрактных классов и интерфейсов.

Answer (score 1):

Если кратко — да, использую, и в своих проектах, и на работе. Почему? Потому что следую парадигме ООП и считаю её хорошей для использования в своём коде.

Почитать про абстракцию, а в частности про интерфейсы (мне когда-то показалась хорошей статья): https://habrahabr.ru/post/30444/

А вот отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (в комментариях тоже предоставили ссылку): [Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (abstract class and interface)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/235352/176064)