# Что значит хорошее понимание ООП?

Tags: ооп, оод

Постоянно просматриваю публикации, чтобы знать, в каком направлении мне стоит двигаться. И вот набрёл на публикацию в которой одним из пунктов является понимание ООП, но написано так:

> Хорошее знание ООП.  Настоящее знание!  Наследования, инкапсуляции
> и полиморфизма мало.

Не могу понять, что имеется ввиду.

Например, есть 4 свойства OOП:

- наследование,
- инкапсуляция,
- полиморфизм,
- абстракция.

Кроме того существуют принципы ООД (паттерны, принципы SOLID, Dependency Injection и т.д.).

Comment: Ничего из перечисленного в вашем посте не является специфичным для ООП. А само ООП может радикально различаться в зависимости от особенностей конкретного языка. Допустим в С++ встроенное объекты это просто структура данных и пачка функций, неявно принимающих указатель на эту структуру, а в javascript (с точки зрения С++) объекты это пара мап. В мультипарадигменных языках, даже если нет встроенной поддержки ООП, ее можно наваять в каком угодно стиле.

Comment: "Кроме того существуют принципы OOD(паттерны, принципы SOLID, Dependency Injection и тд.)" скорей всего именно это и имеется в виду

Comment: а этот-то вопрос зачем переоткрывать? напоминаю: единственной разницей (с текущей ситуацией) будет то, что движок даст возможность оставлять новые ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Имеется ввиду *реальное знание ООП*, то есть понимание что такое объекты, классы, пакеты, интерфейсы и что можно с ними делать. Например объекты можно создавать, удалять, сохранять, сериализовать, и т.д.

Инкапсуляция, наследование и полиморфизм - это примеры того как можно использовать классы и объекты в программировании. То, что этого не доостаточно объясняется тем, что вы можете дать определения этих терминов, но вы не сможете использовать их в *реальном* программировании.

*Реальное* программирование включает себя создание программы, которая будет выполнять какие-то действия при выполнении ее на компьютере. То есть как создавать проект, строить его, управлять его версиями, интегрировать с другими проектами, библиотеками, и т.д.

Почему *реальное* программирование является объектно-ориентированным зависит от языка. Ранее в языках, которые не являются объектно-ориентированными, использовались структуры данных для моделирования реальных объектов. Эти структуры создавались и удалялись при выполнении той или другой процедуры/функции. Но структуры не были связаны с этими процедурами/функциями. Необходимость добавления этих связей привело к ООП.