# Может ли service java содержать дополнительную логику

Tags: java, mvc, service

Пишу проект и такая ситуация что один из методов service получился достаточно длинным. Могу ли я добавить пару static методов для разделения логики или не принято добавлять в service дополнительные методы для обработки данных, т.к по факту он взаимодействует с repository?
Создавать отдельный класс под эти методы и внедрять их в service или прям там писать?

Comment: Создайте в сервисе приватные методы и вынесите доп логику туда Это особенно полезно, если методы могут использоваться повторно.

Comment: Для этого надо понимать как сервисы взаимодействуют с другими классами и в лучшем случае следовать принципам ООП, см. [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/858504/204920) ответ для понимания логики.

Comment: А вообще я думал создать статические методы. А что если их реально в отдельный интерфейс вынесте для данного сервиса?

Comment: Методы взаимодействую по факту с repository просто логика больно длинная получилась и хотелось бы ее разбить