# Вопрос про интерфейсы в c#

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь по-нормальному понять интерфейсы в C# и столкнулся с таким вопросом:

К примеру, я хочу сделать интерфейс, который будет вызываться, если звонит телефон.

Интерфейс:

```
interface iPhone{

void onIncomingCall(String user);

}
```

Класс телефона:

```
public class MyPhone : iPhone{


void onIncomingCall(String user)
{

Console.WriteLine("Нам звонит: "+user);
Console.ReadKey();

}

}
```

И вот вопрос:

В официальной документации интерфейсов в C#

создаётся сначала объект класса, а затем уже объект интерфейса для КОНКРЕТНОГО класса.

```
class Test 
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SampleClass sc = new SampleClass();
        IControl ctrl = (IControl)sc;
        ISurface srfc = (ISurface)sc;

        // The following lines all call the same method.
        sc.Paint();
        ctrl.Paint();
        srfc.Paint();
    }
}

interface IControl
{
    void Paint();
}
interface ISurface
{
    void Paint();
}
class SampleClass : IControl, ISurface
{
    // Both ISurface.Paint and IControl.Paint call this method. 
    public void Paint()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Paint method in SampleClass");
    }
}
```

А если я заранее не знаю, какие у меня вообще классы будут?

Зачем тогда вообще создавать объект интерфейса, а затем вызывать его, если можно просто вызвать метод этого класса через SampleClass.Paint() ?

Как можно вызвать этот метод у всех классов, которые наследуются от этого интерфейса?

Comment: Назовите Ваш интерфейс `IPhone` вместо `iPhone`.

Comment: Кроме того, аккуратнее с формулировками. Здесь `IControl ctrl = (IControl)sc;` не *создается ... объект интерфейса*, а присваивается значение переменной типа `IControl`.

Comment: `я хочу сделать интерфейс, который будет вызываться, если звонит телефон` поясните подробней, что этот текст означает?

Comment: Почитайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/235352/198316), первые три ответа. Там довольно подробно расписано зачем они нужны и чем отличаются от классов.

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно вызвать этот метод у всех классов, которые наследуются от
>   этого интерфейса?

```
public void SomebodyIsCalling(IPhone aPhone, string aCaller)
{
  aPhone.onIncomingCall(aCaller);
}

MyPhone phone1 = new MyPhone();
SomebodyIsCalling(phone1, "Пушкин");

IPhone phone2 = new HisPhone();
SomebodyIsCalling(phone2, "Некрасов");
```

Comment: Ну, опять же, нужно знать заранее, как будут называться классы. P.S Скорее всего, я не понимаю, как это работает :c

Comment: @NoName_as_Null Код внутри функции `SomebodyIsCalling` ничего не знает ни про какие классы

Answer (score 0):

Главное назначение интерфейсов в шарпе - это полиморфизм.

И вот этот пример:

```
SampleClass sc = new SampleClass();
IControl ctrl = (IControl)sc;
ISurface srfc = (ISurface)sc;
```

наглядно демонстрирует не какие-то там вызовы одного и того же, а именно полиморфизм - т.е. способность одного и того же класса иметь разный тип.

В общем, поймите, что такое полиморфизм и сразу станет понятно для чего интерфейсы и как их применять.