# интерфейсы и классы java

Tags: java, интерфейс

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с заданием. Я только начал изучать язык JAVA и пока с этим есть некоторые трудности
Суть задачи:

Задание А:

Создать интерфейс Run, для описания транспорта. Интерфейс должен иметь в себе следующие методы:

1.Метод вывода имени транспортного средства.
2.Метод получения скорости передвижения транспорта
3.Метод получения массы транспорта
4.Метод получения количества пассажиров
5.Метод получения количества колес транспорта

Вот код который я написал

```
public interface Run {
         double getMassBus();   
         double getBusSpeed();  
         int getPassengers();   
         int getWheelAmount(); 
         String getBusInfo();  
}
```

Задание Б:

Создать абстрактный класс Mashine, который реализует интерфейс Run. В данном классе реализовать:

1.Константу максимальной скорости

2.Константу минимальной скорости

3.Константу минимального количества пассажиров

4.Константу максимального количества пассажиров

5.Поле с названием транспорта

6.Поле со скоростью передвижения транспорта в данный момент времени

7.Конструктор класса Mаshinе (String name, int speed)

8.Метод вывода информации о транспорте

Вот что удалось сделать

```
public abstract class Machine implements Run {
final int maxSpeed = 120;   //Константа максимальної швидкості
final int minSpeed = 5;     //Константа мінімальної швидкості
final int maxPasAmount = 30;    //Максимальна к-сть пасажирів
final int minPasAmount = 1;     //Мінімальна к-сть пасажирів

public String busName;      //Поле з назвою транспортного засобу
public double presentSpeed;    //Поле швидкості пересування в даний момент

//Конструктор класу Machine
public Machine(String name, double speed){
    this.presentSpeed = speed;
    this.busName = name;
}

//Реалізація методів з інтерфейсу
abstract public int getWheelAmount();
abstract public int getPassengers();
abstract public double getMassBus();

@Override
public double getBusSpeed(){
    return presentSpeed;
}
@Override
public String getBusInfo(){
    return "Назва " + busName + "\nМакс. шв: " + maxSpeed + "\nМін. шв: " + minSpeed + "\nМакс. к-сть пасажирів: " + maxPasAmount + "\nМін. к-сть пасажирів: " + minPasAmount;
}
```

}

Задание В: На котором все и встало

Создать супер класс "Автобус". От заданного супер класса создать двух прямых потомков "Городской" и "Междугородний двухэтажный". Потомки должны реализовывать все методы, какие нереализованные в абстрактном классе. Данные методы должны выводить на экран информацию о транспорте.

Вот до чего дошел:

```
   public class Bus extends Machine{
    private int wheels, amount;
    private double mass;
    //конструктор
    public Bus(String name, double speed, int wheels, int amount, double mass) {
        super(name, speed);
        this.wheels = wheels;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.mass = mass;
    }
    //методы
    @Override
    public int getWheelAmount(){
        return wheels;
    }
    @Override
    public int getPassengers(){
        return amount;
    }
    @Override
    public double getMassBus(){
        return mass;
    }
}
```

Задание Г:

Создать демонстрационный класс, в котором создаются экземпляры обоих потомков, и производится вызов методов для вывода информации о наше транспорте.

ПРАВИЛЬНО ЛИ БЫЛО РЕАЛИЗОВЫВАТЬ ВСЕ МЕТОДЫ ИЗ ИНТЕРФЕЙСА В АБСТРАКТЕ ИЛИ ПО ЗАДАНИЮ, ЛУЧШЕ СДЕЛАТЬ ИХ В ПОТОМКАХ?
ПОМОГИТЕ, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА ИСПРАВИТЬ НЕДОЧЕТЫ В ПЕРВЫХ ДВУХ ЗАДАНИЯХ И ДОДЕЛАТЬ В И Г. бОЛЬШОЕ ВАМ, ЗАРАНЕЕ, СПАСИБО

Comment: во первых, если вы хотите что-то получить, то название метода должно начинать с get, например getMassBus()

Comment: @danilshik, спасибо, подправил и дописал новое

Comment: @danilshik, к сожалению, к ним не дошел. Если можете - посмотрите, правильно ли по заданиям сделан уже существующий код, если да, то помогите доделать дальше)))

Comment: На самом деле у тебя все стало ещё на задании Б. Вот почитай [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818624/204920).

Comment: @GinTasan Да, еще актуально, ибо я малек запутался. Можете помочь?
пока жду ответа попробую что-то надумать. За любую помощь буду благодарен

Comment: @GinTasan Меня все еще смущает исполнение задания В, так как аргументы из методов убрались. И нужно ли кроме аргументов speed и name прописывать в конструктор bus?

Comment: Необязательно, у вас в задании такого нет, такие вещи решаются в зависимости от задачи, которая стоит в проекте, если это всего лишь примеры, которые надо сделать, то ничего страшного. А геттеры должны возвращать значения из классов, это нормально, это исполнение ООП свойства инкапсуляции, есть еще сеттеры, но раз в задании такого нет - это не важно. Задавайте еще вопросы, могу код написать и скинуть вам, если нужно

Comment: @GinTasan, да, кодом бы крайне помогли. Хотя бы имел бы пример нормальной работы и имел с чем свериться. Я все-таки объявил переменные для гетеров в классе Bus, сейчас обновлю код в вопросе

Comment: Скоро код будет. А так, заметил в Б задании getBusSpeed() , в условии не написано, что его реализовать надо

Comment: @GinTasan Он есть в задании А (в интерфейсе), я не смог нормально передать его в класс Bus и, почему то, решил, что смогу передать в абстрактный класс. Понимаю, что это ошибка, но пока не соображаю. Жду примера дабы разобрать код толкового человека)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий код, объект , конечно создавать в другом классе, не всегда правильно, ибо создает зависимости в коде, однако так написано в задании. Вот код с геттерами и сеттерами.  Все задание сделано.

```js
 interface Run{
double getMassBus();
double getBusSpeed();
int getPassengers();
int getWheelAmount();
String getBusInfo();

//Сеттеры
void setMassBus(double Mass);
void setBusSpeed(double Speed);
void setPassengers(int Pass);
void setWheelAmount(int Wheels);
//
}
  abstract class Machine implements Run{
private final int maxSpeed =120;
private final int minSpeed =5;
private final int maxPasAmount =30;
private final int minPasAmount =1;

private String busName;
private double presentSpeed;

protected Machine(String name,double speed){
this.presentSpeed = speed;
this.busName = name;
}

abstract public double  getMassBus();
abstract public double  getBusSpeed();
abstract public int getPassengers();
abstract public int getWheelAmount();
//Cеттеры
abstract public void  setMassBus(double Mass);
abstract public void  setBusSpeed(double Speed);
abstract public void setPassengers(int Pass);
abstract public void setWheelAmount(int Wheels);
//
@Override
public String getBusInfo(){
return "Название транспорта: " + busName + "  ,Скорость транспорта: " + presentSpeed;
}

      }
            
 class Bus extends Machine{
protected Bus(String name,double speed){
super(name,speed);
}
private double Mass;
private int Pass;
private double Speed;
private int Wheels;
@Override
public double getMassBus(){return Mass;}
@Override
public double getBusSpeed(){return Speed;}
@Override
public int getPassengers(){return Pass;}
@Override
public int getWheelAmount(){return Wheels;} 
//Cеттеры
@Override
public void  setMassBus(double Mass){this.Mass = Mass;};
@Override
public void  setBusSpeed(double Speed){this.Speed = Speed;};
@Override
public void setPassengers(int Pass){this.Pass = Pass;};
@Override
public void setWheelAmount(int Wheels){this.Wheels = Wheels;};
//
}

 class CityBus extends Bus{
public CityBus(String name,double speed){super(name,speed);}

}
 class InterCityBus extends Bus{
public InterCityBus(String name,double speed){super(name,speed);}

}
 class Demo{
public CityBus getCityBus(){
CityBus CB = new CityBus("Газель",50);
CB.setMassBus(500);
CB.setPassengers(20);
CB.setWheelAmount(4);
CB.setBusSpeed(70);
return CB;}
public void getInfoCityBus(CityBus s){
System.out.println("Для Городского автобуса - "+s.getBusInfo() + " Масса: " +s.getMassBus()+ " Скорость:" + s.getBusSpeed() + " Пассажиры: " + s.getPassengers()+ " Колеса: " +s.getWheelAmount() );
}
public InterCityBus getInterCityBus(){
InterCityBus CB = new InterCityBus("Такси",60);
CB.setMassBus(200);
CB.setPassengers(4);
CB.setWheelAmount(4);
CB.setBusSpeed(100);
return CB;}
public void getInfoInterCityBus(InterCityBus s){
System.out.println("Для Межгороднего автобуса - "+s.getBusInfo() + " Масса: " +s.getMassBus()+ " Скорость:" + s.getBusSpeed() + " Пассажиры: " + s.getPassengers()+ " Колеса: " +s.getWheelAmount() );
}
}
class qwer{




public static void main(String[] srgs){
Demo demo = new Demo();
CityBus cb = demo.getCityBus();
InterCityBus icb = demo.getInterCityBus();
demo.getInfoCityBus(cb);
demo.getInfoInterCityBus(icb);

}
}
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, сам бы ещё долго разбирался, а теперь хоть нормальный пример есть. Спасибо, большое

Comment: Не за что , обращайтесь )

Comment: Да, и еще. Не будет ли вам сложно подсказать хороший материал для обучения? Мало ли, может знаете. Либо любой другой совет по изучению

Comment: @ЮрийГалай, По java есть Герберт Шилдт Java 8 Полное Руководство и руководство для начинающих(2015) - это если вы новичок в этом, смотрите вопросы по собеседованиям - jsehelper.blogspot.com/2016/01/blog-post_59.html , очень помогает для того, что бы адаптироваться под различные тонкости работы основ java, дальше начнете понимать куда идти, и что читать, очень важная вещь - паттерны и принципы программирования - ОЧЕНЬ важная часть программирования.

Comment: Есть книга Боба Мартина «Чистый код» , так же есть Java. Эффективное программирование. Джошуа Блох, в ссылке на вопросы на собеседование есть вопросы и о паттернах и о принциппах, но вот еще -javarush.ru/groups/posts/496-patternih-proektirovanija-v-java , javarush.ru/groups/posts/584-patternih-proektirovanija , и в добавочку - dou.ua/lenta/articles/senior-java-tips , удачи в изучении )

Comment: @ЮрийГалай обращайтесь )

Answer (score 3):

Методы получения чего-либо (геттеры) должны быть без аргументов.

> данном классе реализовать:
>
> ...
>
> Метод вывода информации о транспорте

не реализовали.

> Данные методы должны выводить на экран информацию о транспорте.

они у вас ничего не выводят

В абстрактном классе нужно реализовать методы, которые будут иметь одинаковую логику у всех потомков. А в дочерних классов можно переопредилить методы имеющие разную логику. Например `getBusInfo()`.

Для того чтобы реализоваь метод абстрактного класса надо убрать слово `abstract`, и добавить ему логики. В вашем случае надо просто вырезать весь метод `getBusInfo()` включая `@Override` из класса `Bus` и переместить его в класс `Machine`

Для того чтобы переопределить родительский метод достаточно просто переписать его тело (то что находиться в фигурных скобочках) в дочернем классе

Например

```
//это переопределенный метод, с другой логикой
@Override
public String getBusInfo(){
   return "Я Городской автобус!";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, часть из него, я смогу реализовать сам. Но простите, я потому и написал, что бы знающие люди проверили и подсказали. К сожалению, пока не очень понимаю, как реализовать методы в абстракте, а какие в потомках от класса Bus. Если вас не затруднит помочь новичку в этом вопросе, то буду крайне благодарен

Comment: Методы в абстрактном классе лучше оставить также абстрактными, поскольку врядли какое-то поведение можно "обобщить" для всех классов-наследников.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, Хорошо, я убрал из гетеров все аргументы. На сколко я понимаю, в абстрактном классе методы объявлены абстрактными, или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець там в задании написано реализовать 1 абстрактный метод, так что это в любом случае надо будет

Comment: @ЮрийГалай , да в абстрактном классе могут быть абстрактные методы, но это не обязательно

Comment: То есть, мне нужно убрать из АБСТРАКТНОГО класса MACHINE метод  `abstract public String getBusInfo();` и на его место вставить `@Override
public String getBusInfo(){
   return "Назва " + busName + "\nМакс. шв: " + maxSpeed + "\nМін. шв: " + minSpeed + "\nМакс. к-сть пасажирів: " + maxPasAmount + "\nМін. к-сть пасажирів: " + minPasAmount;
}` . Простите если туплю, но я уже запутался почти в край)))

Comment: да,именно это в задании это требуется сделать

Comment: хорошо, где еще есть ошибки?
Как реализовать задания В и Г?
Я внес правки в вопрос

Comment: Ну в В надо создать 2 класса и наследовать их от `Bus`. Но на самом деле я не могу понять что имелось в виду "создать супер класс и реализовать у наследников этого класса абстрактные методы". У супер класса нет абстрактных методов, так что реализовывать его потомкам нечего. Возможно имелось ввиду переопределить методы (очень некорректное задание). Ну а в Г надо просто создать класс (допустим `Main`), создать у него метод `main`, в нем надо создать объекты 2 автобусов и вызвать у них методы

Comment: У меня выводит ошибку в задании В, Что должны возвращать методы из задания В?

Comment: добавь пременную speed

Comment: В конструктор переменная speed попадает через super из абстрактного класса. Мне просто в Bus создать еще одну переменную speed?