# ООП в Java. Относится ли абстракция к принципам ООП?

Tags: java, ооп, терминология

Хотел спросить, относится ли `абстракция` к принципам ООП? Почему на некоторых ресурсах только: `наследование`, `инкапсуляция`, `полиморфизм`?

Comment: Это странное разделение, но однозначного ответа нет. В некоторых книгах оно встречается, причём достаточно известных. Если интересно, то на собеседованиях так и говорите что "наследование, инкапсуляция, полиморфизм, но некоторые ещё выделяют абстракцию"

Comment: полиморфизм это часть абстракции

Comment: наследование и инкапсуляция тоже, мы же наследуем абстрактные классы причём не всегда знаем полную реализацию

Comment: Сколько лет учу ООП, всегда было `наследование, инкапсуляция, полиморфизм`, абстракцию встречаю только в последнее время

Comment: Абстракции используются во всех парадигмах, не только в ООП.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818624/204920

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev получается тогда можно сказать что принципы ООП это: наследование, инкапсуляция, полиморфизм и абстракция на собеседовании допустим и это не будет ошибкой?

Answer (score 2):

Быть может так происходит потому, что инкапсуляция, наследование и полиморфизм - это ООП-специфичные концепты (или по крайней мере более ООП-специфичные). А абстракция - это общий концепт, котрый используется в программировании. И не только в программировании. Это вообще очень важная, глобальная штука. Это способ познания мира. Мы мыслим абстракциями.