# Зачем HashSet и т.д. наследуют и AbstractSet и Set

Tags: java

Ведь класс `AbstractSet` имплементит `Set`. Так зачем реализациям повторно его имплементить?

Comment: Тут надо глубоко мислить. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818624/204920

Answer (score 1):

Это просто сделано для наглядности , чтобы не анализировать всю иерархию для получения информации о типе коллекции. И ещё HashSet может прекратить наследовать AbstractSet, потому что это внутренный класс.