# Возможно ли создать абстрактный класс, наследующий другой абстрактный класс?

Tags: java, extend

Собственно весь вопрос в заголовке, тк только начал изучать джаву, то пока сам не знаю. А ответа в интернете не нашел.

Возможно ли создать абстрактный класс, наследующий другой абстрактный класс?

Как сам понимаю, то можно ведь создать абстрактный класс без методов, только с полями и его уже можно будет наследовать? Или я не прав? И абстрактный класс обязан иметь методы?

Comment: Возможно, не  обязан.

Comment: Про абстрактные классы/ интерфейсы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818624/204920