# Отличие и правильность использования абстрактных классов от интерфейсов в Java

Tags: java, ооп, классы, наследование, интерфейс

Пытаюсь понять чем эти два элемента отличаются. Почитал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235352/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0-abstract-class-and-interface) и [тут](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1985-raznica-mezhdu-abstraktnihmi-klassami-i-interfeysami), а также лекцию которую изучаю. Если я правильно понимаю, кроме определения и подключения я вижу следующее возможности:

**Абстрактный класс**

1. нельзя создать экземпляр класса
2. должны быть определен хотя бы заголовок метода, следовательно наследник обязан переопределять этот метод
3. метод может быть полностью реализован
4. наследнике метод можно переопределить и в итоге получится 1 метод
5. не фиксированные значения переменных

**Интерфейс**

1. нельзя создать экземпляр интерфейса
2. должны быть определены заголовки методов
3. метод можно переопределить и в итоге будет 2 метода (хотя зачем нам столько методов, если достаточно одного)
4. метод можно определить через использование default
5. фиксированные значения переменных

Я понимаю, что интерфейс определяет состояние, а абстрактный класс определяет и состояние и поведение. Почему тогда не пользоваться только одним вариантом, например классом?

Мы можем наследоваться только от одного класса, но от многих интерфейсов. Но почему тогда не создать еще несколько абстрактных классов с наследованием друг от друга и в итоге полученное нечто унаследовать в рабочем классе?

В каких случаях нужно использовать именно то, а не другое?

Есть ли примеры использования в которых именно **необходимо** использовать тот или иной вариант?

Интересует именно применение в Java.

**Дополнение**
Допустим есть такая структура.

```
abstract class Figure {
    double dim1;
    double dim2;

    Figure(double a, double b) {
        dim1 = a;
        dim2 = b;
    }

    abstract double area();
}
```

Есть класс треугольника:

```
class Rectangle extends Figure {
    Rectangle(double a, double b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    double area() {
        System.out.println("B области четырехугольника.");
        return dim1 * dim2;
    }
}
```

Есть класс квадрата:

```
class Triangle extends Figure {
    Triangle(double a, double b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    double area() {
        System.out.println("B области треугольника.");
        return dim1 * dim2 / 2;
    }
}
```

Есть точка входа:

```
class AbsractAreas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(9, 5);
        Triangle t = new Triangle(10, 8);
        Figure figRef = r;
        System.out.println("Площадь равна " + figRef.area());
        figRef = t;
        System.out.println("Площадь равна " + figRef.area());
    }
}
```

Я могу переделать её в интерфейс? Нужно ли её переделать в интерфейс? Или стоит разделить на две части?

*PS:* Дополнительный вопрос к интерфейсам. Я знаю, что интерфейс предназначен для защиты работы класса. Но разве недостаточно наложения ограничений на класс (я имею ввиду модификаторы доступа)?

*PS PS:* Зачем в интерфейс была добавлена возможность определения тела методов?
И вот если я определю в интерфейсе метод например `move (int n)`, а в наследнике мне нужно использовать `move (int n, int m)`. Не проще ли тогда создать абстрактный класс с методом `move ()` и потом переопределять его под нужное количество параметров? Или у имеется возможность для переопределения количества параметров в методе в интерфейсе? Или у нас так и останутся два метода `move (int n)` и `move (int n, int m)`?

*PS PS PS:* Извиняюсь за большое количество вопросов. Просто хотелось бы полностью разобраться с этой темой)

Comment: На самом деле, по-большому счету, это все дело вкуса и практики, что я описал в своем ответе в P.S. Вы можете попробовать сделать так как вам нравится, а потом, если надо, то переделать по-другому. Пробуйте, тренируйтесь, экспериментируйте. Математически точного признака когда что использовать не существует. Программирование это техническое творчество!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интерфейс определяет поведение, в общем смысле интерфейс рассказывает о том, как работать с классом, который этот интерфейс реализует, к примеру все двери умеют закрываться и открываться и на не важно какая это дверь и как она сделана, главное, что это дверь и у неё есть наличие методов для открытия и закрытия. Интерфейс может использоваться классами, которые вообще никак не связаны с друг другом по смыслу (Comparable как пример). И самое важное множественное наследование.

Абстрактный класс определяет поведение и состояние. Абстрактный класс используют для наследования (т.е. мы имеем тесную связь между классами), с помощью него описывают общие черты для наследников. В нем могут находится конкретные (в интерфейсе тоже с java 8) и статические методы.

PS нашел статью, которая скорее всего поможет лучше понять разницу [ссылка](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/431-10-voprosov-po-abstraktnihm-klassam-i-interfeysam-s-sobesedovaniy-po-jazihku-java)

Comment: На примере дверей, если я правильно понимаю, то я должен стремиться сделать абстрактный класс в котором у меня будут поля, например высота, ширина, толщина. А все методы поместить в интерфейс?

Comment: Да, высота, ширина, толщина, будут переопределяться наследниками. Методы нужно разместить в том же абстрактном классе, ибо все двери будут его наследниками, интерфейс в данном случае будет 5й ногой. Интерфейс можно было бы сделать, если у нас появились окна, они тоже умеют закрываться и открываться, но общего с дверью ничего не имеют.

Answer (score 4):

Рассмотрим пример, когда нужны именно интерфейсы и нельзя обойтись абстрактными классами.

Это ситуация, когда нам нужно несколько аспектов функциональности объединить в одном классе, и эти аспекты никак не связанны с собой (так что делать абстрактные классы и наследовать их друг от друга - непрактично или даже невозможно).

Поясню на примере. Допустим нам нужна возможности

1. создавать копии объектов.
2. сравнивать объекты
3. сериализировать объекты в массив байт

Для этого можно либо создать интерфейсы типа:

```
interface Clonable<T> {
  T clone();
}
interface Comparable<T> {
  int compare(T other);
}
interface Serializable {
  byte[] asBytes();
}
```

Либо - создать абстрактные классы с теми же методами.

Нужно понимать, что эти классы или интерфейсы существуют не в вакууме. Мы предполагаем, что у этих интерфейсов (или классов) есть клиенты, например библиотеки, которые их используют. Например, `Serilizable` - часть библиотеки для обмена сообщениями по сети, а `Comparable` - часть библиотеки для работы с коллекциями.

Т.е. где-то существуют функции, которые используют их:

```
  void sort(List<Comparable> list);
```

Теперь когда мы хотим создать конкретный класс который должен уметь и копировать себя, и чтобы его можно было сравнить и чтобы можно было сериализировать, с интерфейсами все просто - делаем класс и реализуем все три интерфейса.

Если же мы использовали абстрактные классы, то возникают проблемы:

1. чтобы иметь все три возможности, какой из классов должен от кого наследоваться?
2. что если у нас все три абстрактных класса в разных библиотеках, которые вообще никак не связаны (делаются разными разработчиками, которые друг о друге не знают, и вообще не знают, что кому то может понадобится использовать класс из другой библиотеки),
3. даже если мы выбрали какой-то способ упорядочить абстрактные классы в иерархию, а нам нужна только частичная функциональность и не нужна функциональность, которую дает класс из корня иерархии, как быть?

Одним словом - для этой задачи абстрактные классы не годятся. Главная причина - это отсутствие множественного наследования в java. Множественное наследование могло бы решить эту проблему, но за счет введения новых проблем (присущих самому множественному наследованию).

Интерфейсы (особенно начиная с java8) могут заменить абстрактные классы (в совокупности с другими мерами). Но иногда использование абстрактного класса может быть более практично.

Допустим, мы создаем библиотеку для сохранения объектов в БД. Можно сделать интерфейс для объекта, который можно сохранять:

```
interfact Persistable<K> {
  K getId();
}
```

Однако в этом случае в каждом конкретном классе, который реализует `Persistable`, придется определять поле `id`. Если таких классов много, то может быть более практично сделать `Persistable` абстрактным классом и тогда он сможет хранить состояние:

```
abstract class Persistable<K> {
  private K id;

  public K getKey() {
    return id;
  }
```

Это конечно простой пример и тут это неоправданно, но если таких полей больше, плюс есть определенные условия, которые должны выполняться относительно этих полей, для того, чтоб объект `Persistable` был правильно сконструирован (например что `id != null`), то тогда делать классы-наследники ответственными за это может быть неудобно, т.к. одна и та же логика будет находиться в нескольких местах и удобней с точки зрения поддержки иметь ее в одно месте.

Это может помочь выявить ошибки в наследниках, когда наследник (не по злому умыслу) неправильно реализует интерфейс, на более ранних стадиях.

Конечно у наследования реализации и использования абстрактных классов есть минусы, которые нужно учитывать, и взвешивать за и против в конкретном случае.

Comment: А как быть с методами интерфейсов у которых должно быть определено разное количество входящих параметров? Реализовывать n интерфейсов?

Comment: Всегда следует смотреть на вопрос определения ответственностей классов и интерейсов с точки зрения клиентов класса/интерфейса. Если есть смысл (т.е. один и тот же клиент должен/может вызывать разные методы) - то нужно поместить их в один интерфейс. Если предназначение у них разное - то скорее разные интерфейсы. Отвечать на абстрактный вопрос трудно, т.к. трудно сформулировать четкие критерии, тут скорее пример проблемы нужен.

Comment: Ага, вижу что вопрос дополнен, пока писал ответ. Дополню и ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Интерфейс - это, по-большей части, некий признак общего поведения. Например, если у вас объект может быть клонируемым, то среди предков его класса наверняка есть интерфейс `Cloneable`. Если объект передвигаемый, то - `Moveable` и так далее. И методы у признаков соответствующие - их цель это обозначить!, а не реализовать поведение объекта класса наследника признака-интерфейса.

Абстрактный класс - это все-таки класс, или "недокласс". То есть сущность, которая такая же как и конкретный класс, но ему чего-то не хватает.

Например, абстрактный класс `Shape (Форма)` вполне себе сущность/класс, но мы не можем сказать, что именно эта за форма (куб, квадрат, круг, параллелепипед), например, мы не можем сказать как ее отрисовать, или схватить, или изменить, сколько у нее вершин и ребер, поэтому данная сущность вполне может иметь какую-то частичную реализацию, например методы изменения и хранение положения центра формы в пространстве, или на плоскости, но отображение и конкретное поведение такой сущности мы, все-таки, оставим потомкам/наследникам.

Обе конструкции, кроме всего прочего, сами по себе могут быть наследниками таких же интерфейсов и абстрактных классов, если в этом есть архитектурная/смысловая необходимость.

З.Ы. Лучше всего поможет понять разницу - практика! В процессе разработки архитектуры приложения и последующей реализации одни из те же сущности могут стать вначале интерфейсами, а потом классами (и даже абстрактными), а потом наоборот )

Comment: Но ведь Форма или фигура это родственник куба, квадрата и т.д, т.е. родовая черта, признак, т.е это можно реализовать именно и как интерфейс?!

Comment: @Александр можно, но суть в том, что у формы уже есть какое-то состояние и не абстрактное поведение (например, изменение положение центра формы, то есть метод setMove вполне может быть реализуем), поэтому более логично сделать форму абстрактным классом, чего не скажешь про Cloneable, например, или Serializable. Как говорится, почувствуйте разницу