# Default в интерфейсе vs абстрактный класс

Tags: java, default

Сперва предисловие, чтобы поняли суть вопроса:
Поскольку учить программирование я начал в универе с С++, для меня абстрактный класс и интерфейс отличаются только реализацией: если класс только из абстрактных методов, которые обязательно нужно будет переопределить у наследников (нет обычных методов с реализацией) то это интерфейс. В Java у меня сломался мозг, потому что при помощи `default`- методов можно написать реализацию в классе, который мы изначально специально помечаем как интерфейс (даже специальным отдельным ключевым словом). Хотя по факту я же могу просто написать обычный абстрактный класс с реализацией в тех функциях, где надо. Так в чём разница между обычными методами с реализацией в абстрактных классах и `default` в интерфейсах? Неужели не хватало одного варианта?

Comment: Рекомендую озакомиться с главой 9 книги "Философия java" (у меня 4ое издание, в другом издании может быть другой номер главы), там этот вопрос очень подробно с примерами рассматривается. Лучше чем Эккель и не объяснить.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java 8 interface и abstract class](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491171/); [Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235352/)

Comment: Если вкратце, дефолтные методы были добавлены в Java 8 в интерфейсы в связи с появлением Stream API, чтобы упростить расширение функциональных возможностей уже существующих интерфейсов типа [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (добавлены методы `replaceAll`. `sort`, `spliterator`), [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) (`stream`/`parallelStream`, `removeIf`, `spliterator`) и т.д., не ломая обратную совместимость.

Comment: Ещё один связанный вопрос: [Отличие и правильность использования абстрактных классов от интерфейсов в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1133215/)