# Больше переменных или объёмнее конструктор?

Tags: java, ооп, дизайн

Пишу тестовое сейчас на понимание ООП в Java и столкнулся с таким диссонансом:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    protected String color;
    protected double area;

    Shape() {
        color = null;
        area = 0;
    }
    Shape (String color, double area) {
        this.color = color;
        this.area = area;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public abstract double getArea();
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Shape: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " color: " + color;
    }
}

class Square extends Shape {
    private double side;

    Square(double side) {
        super(Colors.YELLOW.name(), side * side);
        this.side = side;
    }
    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }
    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return area;
    }


}
```

Переменная area вроде как излишня. Её можно убрать, в конструкторы меньше инфы передавать и вычисления делать в геттере `getArea()`.

**Вот так:**

```
    public abstract class Shape {
    protected String color;

    Shape() {
        color = null;
    }
    Shape (String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public abstract double getArea();
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Shape: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " color: " + color;
    }
}

class Square extends Shape {
    private double side;

    Square(double side) {
        super(Colors.YELLOW.name());
        this.side = side;
    }
    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }
    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return side * side;
    }


}
```

С одной стороны мне кажется, что это будет трудно читаемо и памяти потребуется куда больше (представим цикл, который с каждой итерацией будет не смотреть значение в переменной, а постоянно по новой его вычислять), а с другой, что так неправильно и появится куча лишних ненужных переменных, а конструктор будет перегружен их инициализацией.

Comment: Если вы начали убирать переменные из абстрактного класса, то возможно вам нужен интерфейс. См. в чем отличие абстрактного класса от интерфейса [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818624/204920).

Comment: Идея передавать площадь при создании фигуры кажется странной,учитывая, что, например, прямоугольников с одинаковой площадью бесконечное множество. Возможно для ваших задач необходимо иметь такой конструктор конечно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> С одной стороны мне кажется, что это будет трудно читаемо

Читабельность ничуть не пострадает, а вот вероятность совершить ошибку при передаче неправильного значения исчезает

> и памяти потребуется куда больше

Как раз наоборот - памяти нужно меньше. Т.к. меньше статической информации. Один `double` это восемь байт. Если у вас 1000 объектов, то это экономия 8000 байт.

> (представим цикл, который с каждой итерацией будет не смотреть значение в переменной, а постоянно по новой его вычислять),

А вот время получения значения, действительно увеличится. И тут нужно смотреть, что в приоритете. Если у **одного объекта** метод `getArea()` вызывается один-два раза за время жизни объекта, то оставьте его как есть с динамическим вычислением. Если 100 раз в цикле, то вызовите его один раз за пределами цикла и сохраните в переменную. А если 1000 раз в разных местах программы, то тогда нужно вводить отдельное поле класса и таки передать его в конструктор базового класса:

```java
 public abstract class Shape {
    private double area;
    protected String color;

    Shape(double area) {
        this(null, area);
    }

    Shape (String color, double area) {
        this.color = color;
        this.area = area;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Shape: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " color: " + color;
    }
}

class Square extends Shape {
    private double side;

    Square(double side) {
        super(Colors.YELLOW.name(), side * side);
        this.side = side;
    }
    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }
}
```

Comment: Кхм, кхм. И чему же будет равно `area` при `calcArea()`, вызванном из родительского конструктора до выполнения `this.side = side;`?

Comment: @Igor Упс! Исправил. Все таки дурацкое требование джавы, что вызов `super()` должен идти первым

Answer (score 6):

Вопросы производительности и памяти должны возникать тогда, когда у вас есть проблемы с производительностью и памятью. При проектировании классов производительность не является определяющим критерием.

Для начала надо ответить на вопрос - а какую информацию вообще должен содержать базовый класс Shape? Какие у вас есть требования к нему?

Вот вы передаете ему цвет и площадь, а надо ли ему знать об этом? Как этот класс будет использовать эту информацию? Требует ли класс знать цвет и площадь при конструировании обекта или каждый наследник просто должен иметь методы для извлечения цвета и площади?

Допустим, мы явно хотим сказать, что при создании объекта, мы уже должны знать цвет и площадь и они неизменны. Мы это можем выразить вот так

```java
public abstract class Shape {

    protected String color;
    protected double area;
    
    Shape (String color, double area) {
        this.color = color;
        this.area = area;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return area;
    }
}
```

Код выше выражает наши требования для всех наследников, нельзя будет создать наследника не указав цвет и область.

Вот теперь вы озадачились вопросом вычисления площади. Например, вы можете хотеть эту площадь лениво вычислять, а цвет объекта вообще может быть будет изменяемым? В таком случае, базовый класс не может требовать этих параметров при создании, нет в этом смысла. Это уже другие требования к классу. Вы можете сказать, ок, мы не знаем как именно наследник будет вычислять или получать цвет и площадь, но он должен предоставить методы для их извлечения.

```java
public abstract class Shape {

    public abstract String getColor();
    public abstract double getArea();    
}
```

Теперь каждый наследник сам решает, как и когда он получит цвет/площадь.

Таким образом, ваш код явно должен выражать ваши ожидания от класса. Это идет не от соображений читаемости, а от ваших требований и архитектуры. Вы должны определить для своей системы - что есть Shape? Как этот базовый класс должен работать с наследниками? Что должны делать наследники? Какие формы вы будете наследовать? Как эти наследники должны себя вести, какие у них должны быть поля? Что вы знаете о полях и что вы не знаете? Какие у вас есть сценарии использоваия ваших форм? И т.д.

Comment: Хороший ответ и рекомендации! :)