# Что такое состояния в Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, интерфейс

Смотрел видеоурок по Kotlin, в котором было сказано, что абстрактные классы отличаются от интерфейсов тем, что абстрактные классы могут хранить состояния, а интерфейсы нет. Попробовал загуглить, что такое состояния, но конкретно этого слова нигде не нишёл.
В сфзи с этим у меня вопрос - что такое состояния в Kotlin?

Comment: Автор имеет в виду поля (члены) класса. Ничего специфически-котлинского в этом нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[отличия интерфейсов и абстрактных классов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/235352/452965)

Состояние, это информация содержащаяся в структуре, хранить состояние
- может быть несколько объектов с одинаковой логикой, но разным содержимым. Яркий пример отсутствия состояния - `Enum`, каждый его объект общий для всего приложения. В то время как классы могут иметь разное состояние, в зависимости от инициализации. Если в структуре есть что-то, что позволяет хранить данные и при этом создавать разные объекты - то эти данные и будут называться состоянием.

например:

```
class StatelessClass { // статичное состояние у класса
    val someInt = 1
}

class StatefullClass { // динамическое состояние
    var someInt = 1
}
```

Если сделаем так, то у класса уже будет изменяться состояние, что и называет хранить состояние:

```
class StatefullClass(val someInt: Int = 1)
```

Потому что можно будет создать объекты с разным состоянием.

Как я это понимаю, не уверен, что удалось прояснить ситуацию. :)