# Имеют ли место static-функции в интерфейсном классе?

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++

Знаю, что согласно стандарту, интерфейсный класс -  который не имеет переменных-членов и все методы которого являются чистыми виртуальными функциями. Собственно вопрос, если в интерфейсном классе присутствует статический метод - значит класс перестает быть интерфейсом и становится абстрактным классом? хотелось бы разобраться, спасибо!

Comment: Какому стандарту? В С++ нет термина "интерфейсный класс".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ок, поищем в стандарте

> 10.4 Abstract classes
> An abstract class can also be used to define an interface for which derived classes provide a variety of implementations

далее

> An **abstract class** is a class that can be used only as a base class of some other class; no objects of an abstract class can be created except as subobjects of a class derived from it. A class **is abstract** if it has **at least one pure virtual function**.

То есть, если класс абстрактный, он может использоваться как интерфейс. Там нет упоминания об отсутствии переменных-членов или то, что все функции должны быть виртуальными. Только о том, что хотя бы одна.

В целом, раньше оно так и было, что только виртуальные функции. И java, как язык, который пытается быть чисто ООП (хотя по факту таким не является), предоставлял такую сущность как интерфейс. Почему предоставлял? да потому что теперь интерфейсы в java могут иметь "реализации по умолчанию", но при этом все равно быть интерфейсами.

Поэтому, скорее всего ответ будет такой - все зависит от Вашего виденья или принятых в команде соглашений. По моему мнению - да, может быть статическая функция. Но скорее всего найдутся люди, которые будут считать, что класс не может быть интерфейсом, если его имя не начинается на букву `I`.

Вот ещё один вопрос, где я более подробно отвечал и там много интересных комментариев [Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (abstract class and interface)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235352/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0-abstract-class-and-interface/235367#235367)