# Объект интерфейса?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, что тут происходит?

Я создал интерфейс `VariablesAndMethodsWithoutModifiers`, указал в нем 2 метода и 1 константу (переменную или свойство ?).
В `main` мне разрешило создать объект (?) этого интерфейса, с описанием реализации всех методов.
Далее через этот "объект" я могу использовать методы и свойства, описанные в интерфейсе.

Но после последней фигурной скобки требовало точку с запятой (;) и от интерфейсов нельзя создавать обьекты.

Что же было создано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: анонимный класс.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndnubpPzkNE

Comment: [This appears to create an object from an interface; how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3947708/2881286)

Comment: [В чем отличие абстрактного класса от интерфейса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818624/204920)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *1 константу (переменную или свойство ?)*

В интерфейсах в качестве полей можно объявлять только *константы*.

[JLS 9.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3):
Каждое объявление поля внутри интерфейса по умолчанию является `public`, `static`, `final`.  Для таких полей допускается избыточное указание нескольких или всех таких модификаторов.

Аналогично, все методы в интерфейсе неявно имеют модификаторы `public`.

---

> *В main мне разрешило создать объект (?) этого интерфейса с описанием реализации всех методов.*

Экземпляр интерфейса создать невозможно, так как интерфейсы по умолчанию абстрактные, в том числе даже если интерфейс является маркером и не содержит никаких абстрактных методов или содержит только реализации статических/дефолтных методов:

```
interface MyInterface {
    default void foo() {}
}

MyInterface interfaceInstance = new MyInterface(); // compilation error: MyInterface is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Serializable serializable = new Serializable(); // compilation error: Serializable is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

При описании реализации всех методов (множество абстрактных методов интерфейса может быть пустым) создаётся анонимный внутренний класс и соответственно экземпляр такого класса.

```java
MyInterface myInstance = new MyInterface() {}; // ok, only default method
System.out.println(myInstance.getClass());
// class MyClass$1
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myInstance.getClass().getInterfaces()));
// [interface MyInterface]

Serializable serializable = new Serializable() {}; // ok, marker interface
System.out.println(serializable.getClass());
// class MyClass$2
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(serializable.getClass().getInterfaces()));
// [interface java.io.Serializable]
```

Comment: @AAlex Rudenko
Спасибо огромное, помогли разобраться
Почитал про анонимный класс