# Абстрактные классы и интерфейсы для чего и что всё же?

Tags: c#

**1. Абстрактный класс**

По сути это самый обычный класс. Только что мы не можем создать объект такого класса. Как я читал, это класс, который говорит об объекте абстрактно. То есть мы можем в классе реализовать методы, но не можем создать его объект.

**2. Интерфейсы**

Нельзя реализовывать методы, поля только статичные и константы. И несмотря на то, что нельзя реализовывать методы, я нахожу пример с метанита, где реализован метод по умолчанию:

```
interface IMovable
{
    void Move()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Walking");
    }
    // реализация свойства по умолчанию
    // свойство только для чтения
    int MaxSpeed { get { return 0; } }
}
```

и ещё вопрос. Интерфейс и абстрактный класс они же получается ссылочные типы?

Comment: Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235352/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0-abstract-class-and-interface) уже ответ есть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос по сути про ООП наследование и полиморфизм.

Члены класса могут быть обычными, абстрактными и виртуальными.

- Обычный член не может быть переопределен в наследниках, а только заменен.
- Виртуальный член может быть переопределен, а может и нет (полиморфизм)
- Абстрактный член должен быть переопределен

Абстрактный класс "должен быть переопределен", то есть унаследован, так как может содержать нереализованные (абстрактные) члены.

Экземпляр абстрактного класса невозможно создать. Класс - это по сути шаблон для создания объекта. Абстрактный класс - частичный шаблон, то есть самого по себе абстрактного класса недостаточно для создания объекта, и недостающие части реализуются в неследнике.

Интерфейс - частный случай абстрактного класса, где все члены по умолчанию абстрактные и не приватные, при этом полностью отсутствует и не может быть определен конструктор.

Начиная с C# 8.0 (.NET Core 3.1) появились так называемые Default Interface Methods (DIM), где стало допустимо вставлять в методы изначальную реализацию. Эти методы технически считаются виртуальными в обязательном порядке. Сами по себе DIM - сомнительная затея, нарушают целостность структуры приложения, дают возможность внедрения кода в абстракции. Это как бы удобно, когда у вас есть проект-монстр размером с Visual Studio, но кроме этого плюсов от данного нововведения нет, только всякие [баги](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43340), с которыми даже Microsoft не знает, что делать. Не используйте DIM без особой надобности.

При реализации интерфейса обязательно переопределение всех его членов кроме DIM. При этом при переопределении виртуальных членов абстрактного класса нужно использовать ключевое слово `override`, а при переопределении виртуальных членов интерфейса - не нужно, так как оно само по себе подразумевается.

Основное преимущество интерфейса перед абстрактным классом - множественное наследование. То есть не наследование, а "реализация", один класс может реализовать несколько интерфейсов одновременно. В случае с абстрактным классом класс-наследник может наследовать только один радительский класс.

Говоря простым языком, да, интерфейс - это ссылочный тип. Но интерфейс - "обертка" над классом, асбтракция, он не может быть сам по себе ссылочным или значимым типом, вы не можете создать объект типа "интерфейс". Он - сама ссылка, а внутри объект - конкретный экземпляр класса. Все что вы можете, это создать обычный экземпляр и сделать апкаст типа его ссылки до реализованного этим классом интерфейса.

Comment: Насчёт бага, что описан на гитхабе, я бы немного не согласился: там просто virtual метода на уровне низшего класса выполняет override метода интерфейса, правда пока понимание дойдёт до принципа - мозги сплавятся. Просто это не интуитивно и сложнее ещё и по той причине, что наследование без интерфейсов - так не работает.