# Интерфейс или абстрактный класс ?(теория)

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс, теория

Можете объяснить что имеется в виду:

"Лучше использовать интерфейс,если хотим определить поведение конкретного типа данных,но нам не важно кто его реализует"

Comment: В классическом интерфейсе нет кода. В абстрактном классе может быть. После этого все должно стать на свои места.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (abstract class and interface)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235352/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0-abstract-class-and-interface)

Answer (score 1):

есть следующие классы:
Человек, Машина, Самолет, Муха, Велосипед.

каждый из них должен иметь возможность "Передвижение".
лучше это сделать через Интерфейс, чем наследовать их чего-то абстрактного, ведь ничто их не связывает и тем более ни один из этих классов не может быть дочерним другого.