# В чем различие между высоким, средним и низким уровнями абстракций?

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем различие между **высоким, средним и низким** уровнями абстракций. Вопрос возник из за [Листинг 3.1](https://coollib.com/b/486351-robert-sesil-martin-chistyiy-kod-sozdanie-analiz-i-refaktoring/read).(Ctrl+F --- 3.1) Почему в данном случае `getHtml()` - очень высокий уровень? `String pagePathName = PathParser.render(pagePath)` - средний уровень, а .append("\n") - чрезвычайно низкий уровень?

Comment: А там рядышком есть объяснение почему.

> Чтобы убедиться в том, что функция выполняет «только одну операцию», необходимо проверить, что все команды функции находятся на одном уровне абстракции.

Comment: @KoVadim то есть, чем меньше операций, тем ниже уровень? Можно ли тогда сказать, что методы, которые относятся к определенному языку программирования(например: println) - это всегда низкий уровень? И почему `String pagePathName = PathParser.render(pagePath)` - средний уровень или если взять только `PathParser.render(pagePath)` - то можно отнести к низкому уровню?

Comment: Уровень абстракции это очень абстрактно. Но кол-во операций никак не определяет уровень. Почитайте ещё раз определение с книги.

Comment: Похоже, что вы или автор книги не правильно понимаете абстрактность. Абстрактность предполагает сокрытие кода или данных. Это один из основных принципов ООП. К чему относится абстракция? У вас есть абстрактный класс или метод? Или то что вы называете абстракцией абстрактным быть не может. Почитайте лучше про абстракцию в программировании [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818624/204920).

Comment: Ну, если Роберт Мартин (дядя Боб - автор книги) плохо разбирается в теме...  Если код низкоабстрактный, то он очень сильно закладывается на детали реализации (тот же перевод строки). Если код высокоабстрактный, то он может читаться почти как художественное произведение и в некоторых случаях даже выглядеть почти одинаково на разных языках.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Приведу пример. Допустим у вас есть инструкция запуска ракеты в космос (или если хотите алгоритм запуска). Представьте себе такое описание:

```
1. нажмите 3-ю кнопку в 4-ом ряду на панели А
2. переключите тумблер 8 в позицию ВКЛ
3. переведите рычаг СКР на деление 4
...
100. нажмите зеленую кнопку во 2-ом ряду
```

И второе описание:

```
1. включите систему пожаротушения
2. включите систему рассчета курса
...
20. запустите главный двигатель
```

Так вот первое описание оно очень детальное, еще говорят низкоуровневое, или еще по другому - на низком уровне абстракции. Тут каждый шаг предельно конкретен и понятен, в том смысле, что ясно как его исполнить, но не всегда понятно к чему он приведет и зачем нужен.

Второе же описание более высокоуровневое, т.е. на высоком уровне абстракции. Отдельные шаги дают понимание "что" нужно делать и зачем шаг предназначен, но не обязательно понятно "как" это делать, может потребоваться дополнительное пояснение.

Обратите внимание, что шаг 100 в первом описании и шаг 20 во втором по сути означают то же самое. Только шаг 100 описывает действие на низком уровне абстрации, а шаг 20 - на высоком. Это демонстарция того, что количество операций не является решающим фактором для того является ли что-то высоко- или низкоабстрактным.

Так же важно понимать, что уровень абстракции это понятие относительное. Одно и то же описание шага в каком-то контексте будет на высоком уровне абстракции, а в другом - на низком. Можно только сравнить два описания и сказать, что один более абстрактный, а другой менее.

В том тексте речь идет о том, что плохо когда уровни абстракции смешиваются. Это как если бы инструкция была такая:

1. нажмите 3-ю кнопку в 4-ом ряду на панели А
2. включите систему рассчета курса
3. дерните за рычаг СКР
   и т.д.