# Как переопределить метод equals в интерфейсе?

Tags: java, интерфейс, переопределение

Я создал интерфейс.
В нём хочу переопределить метод `equals()`:

```
default boolean equals (OverdueControlActivityProjection other) {
  System.out.println("Вызывается метод equals в интерфейсе");
  return getControlActivityId().equals(other.getControlActivityId());
}
```

На затем,
когда я использую стрим, я ожидаю, что метод distinct должен вызывать метод `equals()`:

```
Stream.of(projection1, projection2)
      .distinct()
      .collect(Collectors.toList);
```

Но он его не вызывает. Я ведь не вижу в консоли вывода.
Почему не работает?
Как я смогу убрать дубликаты интерфейсов, если дублируются по полю `controlActivityId`?

Comment: Вы не переопределили метод `equals()`, а определили свой

Comment: Я не могу добавить аннотацию Override

Comment: Почему бы не сделать общий метод в общем абстрактном классе, от которого наследуются контролы (или что там)?

Comment: *Я не могу добавить аннотацию Override* - немудрено, потому что то, что вы написали, не является переопределением метода

Answer (score 2):

Переопределение методов класса `Object` в интерфейсе как дефолтных методов вполне бессмысленно, так как такие методы всё равно будут недостижимые (unreachable).

Дело в том, что реализация метода *в классе* всегда имеет высший приоритет по сравнению с дефолтной реализацией *в интерфейсе*, даже если эта реализация выполнена в классе `Object`.

Поэтому и возникает ошибка компиляции `Default method 'equals' overrides a member of 'java.lang.Object'` при попытке переопределить метод с сигнатурой `public boolean equals(Object o)`:

```java
interface Foo {
    int foo();

    @Override
    default boolean equals(Object o) { // ошибка компиляции
        return false;
    }
}
```

А определение метода `boolean equals(Foo f)` в интерфейсе не является переопределением соответствующего метода, о чём указано в комментариях (аннотация `@Override` не может применяться).

---

Выход заключается только в использовании абстрактного класса, но для корректной фильтрации при помощи `distinct` потребуется также переопределить метод `hashCode`:

```java
interface GoodFoo {
    int foo();
}

abstract class FooImpl implements GoodFoo {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        return o instanceof GoodFoo && this.foo() == ((GoodFoo) o).foo();
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return foo();
    }
}
```

Тест:

```java
List<GoodFoo> foos = Arrays.asList(
    new FooImpl() {
        @Override public int foo() { return 1; }
    }, 
    new FooImpl() {
        @Override public int foo() { return 2; }
    },
    new FooImpl() {
        @Override public int foo() { return 1; }
    }
);
foos.stream()
    .distinct()
    .mapToInt(GoodFoo::foo)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
```

---

Связанный вопрос на основном SO: [Java8: Why is it forbidden to define a default method for a method from `java.lang.Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016962/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Чтобы переопределить метод нужно повторить его сигнатуру и возвращаемое значение. Смотрим в [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) и видим, что он объявлен как:

```java
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

То есть он возвращает `boolean`, а принимает на вход `Object`. У вас же в параметрах тип `OverdueControlActivityProjection`. Вы указываете свой конкретный тип. А это объявление другого метода, достаточно вспомнить про *перегрузку методов* (англ. *methods overloading*).

Для переопределения прописываем метод так, как он написан в `Object`. Добавляем аннотацию `@Override`:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    //Тут будем писать реализацию метода
}
```

Внутри метода уже можно из типа `Object` получить ваш тип `OverdueControlActivityProjection`. Проводим *нисходящее преобразование* (англ. *downcasting*):

```java
OverdueControlActivityProjection otherObject = (OverdueControlActivityProjection) obj;
```

И дальше пишем реализацию. Хотя надо иметь в виду случай, когда в параметрах придёт `null`:

```java
if(obj == null) return false;
```

2. Переопределение метода в интерфейсе — это что вообще? Если вы понимаете, какая у классов-наследников будет реализация `equals()`, то вам нужен абстрактный класс. Смотрите вопрос [Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (abstract class and interface)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/235352/532877) и ответы на него.

Comment: *Переопределение метода в интерфейсе — это что вообще?* .... *"Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (abstract class and interface)"*  --- эти данные немного устарели.... и Java накостылял костыли..... теперь у Java (уже не один год) можно писать методы в интерфейсах  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Тут пока я эти строки печатал написали [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1560875/532877), что это невозможно :) Писать методы можно, переопределять нельзя.

Comment: Там ответ о "невозможности" не по причине, что в интерфейсе нельзя методы писать, а по другой причине.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не говорил, что писать нельзя — да, есть в Java модификатор default.

Comment: ну п.2, я так понимаю, говорит об обратном

Comment: @АлексейШиманский *"Переопределение метода в интерфейсе — это что вообще?"* намекает, что переопределение невозможно. Про то, что писать нельзя сами по себе методы, нет ни слова.

Comment: А, ок, значит не так понял